# What type of font is this?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to find the type of fonts from this definition [image: definition]. Specially for the words:
Combine,Reveal,gen,enc,dec. An experienced user might know this font

Comment: Side note: that has to be one of the most hard-to-decipher definitions I've ever stumbled upon. And not because of the typography - that part's fine - but because of all the cross-referencing. (Might have to do with the fact that it's completely out of my field, too :P)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Comment: @doncherry I believe it's not "how to find the name of the fonts", but "how do I produce those font variations with LaTeX". The actual fonts used are not relevant, IMO.

Comment: @egreg: Good point. That makes me think of a one-catches-all question "What are the different fonts that I can use in math mode?", would that make sense?

Comment: @doncherry I guess it would be a good question.

Comment: @egreg Done: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/4012

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That "gen" is obtained with `\mathsf`, while "Reveal" with `\mathtt`. Here's a way to write that passage; I added some personal commands in order to abstract the font assignments, so that changing them is a matter of only changing the definition in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\afunc}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bfunc}[1]{\operatorname{\mathtt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\contract}[1][\mathcal{C}]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
A contract function \(f_{\contract}\colon\Set{P}^{*}\to\Set{R}\) is said
to support cryptodatabases processing under the encryption scheme
\(\langle\afunc{gen},\afunc{enc},\afunc{dec}\rangle\) if the following
condition holds: there exist two functions \(\bfunc{Combine}\) and
\(\bfunc{Reveal}\) so that, for any \(n\in\Set{N}\) and any
\(m_{1},\dots,m_{n}\in\afunc{D}_{\contract}\), if
\(\langle pk,sk\rangle\gets\afunc{gen}(1^n)\),
\(c_{i}\gets\afunc{enc}(pk,m_{i})\) for \(i=1,\dots,n\) and
\(c\gets\bfunc{Combine}(c_{1},\dots,c_{n})\), then we have
\(\bfunc{Reveal}(sk,c)=f_{\contract}(m_{1},\dots,m_{n})\).
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]