# traditional German sans-serif (and serif) blackboard-bold symbols

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, blackboard

What I have always been looking for in LaTeX were traditional German sans-serif blackboard-bold letters, mainly for: N (natural numbers), Z (integers), Q (rational numbers), R (reals), C (complex numbers).

These five symbols are used widely in German secondary-school math textbooks and in a type of book called "Formelsammlung" (a book that functions as a collection of formulas; usually secondary school students will use one for math and physics each). The most widely used Formelsammlung was (for a long time at least) "Mathematische Formeln / Erweiterte Ausgabe E" by Sieber/Klett.

The standard array of German textbook publishers (such as Cornelsen and Klett; I'm afraid I don't remember which math textbook my school used) always styled the blackboard-bold letters in a particular, uniform way: **for sans-serif letters this was with the doublestroke having equal strength as the one that it is doubling, and also without a connection to the original stroke (for vertical-ish doubled strokes)**. The symbols look very similar (and are I think homotopy-equivalent (a notion from topology)) to the ones of `dsfont`'s `sans` option (`\(\mathds{N},\mathds{Z},\mathds{Q},\mathds{R},\mathds{C}\)`), except I see that the vertical stroke for "Q" is rendered imperfectly in my viewer (the vertical stroke is not perfectly connected at the bottom) but not all viewers it seems; also for "A" we'd expect the doubled stroke to be on the left (though technically German secondary school math has no precedent here, since "A" is not commonly used to denote a specific set).

**Important:** After initially posting my question, I do believe to remember that there are *both* sans-serif and serif styles in standard German schoolbooks and (at least lower-division) math textbooks. As for serif letters, the `\varmathbb` symbols of the `txfonts` package look very close to what I remember. (I initially thought that the doubled stroke for at least Z was too thin there, but now I don't remember whether this perhaps applied only to the German sans-serif style.)

**Is anyone aware of a DIN standard defining the proper symbols?** I suspect there might be one.

**Much more importantly, is anyone aware of a font for (La)TeX that provides the type of blackboard bold symbols that are commonly used in German school literature for both (a) sans-serif and (b) serif styles?**

(I can not find online scans of this literature and do not have easy access to it right now. If someone else can help out here that would be much appreciated.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The definitive answer turns out to be quite distributed (found through collaborative discussion). Credit goes to multiple people (see the entire discussion). Awarding bounties would have been infeasible in this case as they would have to be distributed over a few people.*

**Sans-serif:** Package `mathds` with option `sans` (`\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}`), except for doublestroke-"A" one needs to use `\mathds{a}` instead of `\mathds{A}` to get the doubled stroke on the "correct" (as per expectation) side (i.e., on the left).

**Serif:** The following fonts mentioned in `mathalfa`'s documentation would "pass" to the eye of a German user used to the traditional lettershapes of German blackboard bold: `pazo` (Mathpazo bb), `tx` (tx bb), `px` (px bb). "tx bb" looks closest to my memories, though I like the "S" of Mathpazo bb as being more consistent with the implicit design. The `mathds` package also yields letters whose shapes "pass" for "traditional German" appearance, except for the doublestroke-"A", one needs to remember to use the lowercase option (`\mathds{aBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}`), just like I mentioned above in the sans-serif paragraph.

Answer (score 19):

I suggest you take a look at Michael Sharpe's [mathalfa](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha) (the spelling "mathalpha" works too) package. In the package's user guide, the author lists *five* "hollowed-out" and *fourteen* [!] "geometric" variants of blackboard-bold fonts. (Note that not all of the underlying fonts are free.) I trust that one or more of the math blackboard board fonts listed and/or made available through the `mathalfa` package will meet your needs. (I'm afraid I don't have access to German-language math textbooks.)

A big plus of using the `mathalfa` package is that you can "mix and match" various math alphabets (blackboard bold, caligraphic, curly, script, fraktur, etc) with ease. Excerpting from the README file that comes with the mathalfa package:

> This package provides a standard means of setting math alphabets 
>   associated with the macros \mathcal, \mathbb, \mathfrak and \mathscr
>   and, where available, their bold counterparts \mathbcal, \mathbbb, 
>   \mathbfrak and \mathbscr.
>
> It mostly bypasses the usual fd and sty files used to load these 
>   alphabets in order to allow each to be scaled independently and 
>   without silently quantizing the sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! As far as serif styles are concerned, I'd say the following choices would "pass" to an eye used to German-style blackboard bold: `pazo` (Mathpazo bb), `tx` (tx bb), `px` (px bb). Note that one decisive criterion here is the doubling of N with the vertical stroke on the left (and not the diagonal middle stroke). "tx bb" looks closest to my memories, though I like the "S" of Mathpazo bb as being more consistent with the implicit design.

Comment: For sans-serif: The font `mt` (Mathtime Pro 2 bb) seems like a candidate, but it violates the fact that the German textbook style I'm looking for has unconnected (not hollowed-out) doubled strokes on the left for "N" and "R" (for the sans-serif style only), and it looks too modern-fancy in glyph design.

Answer (score 2):

*(Note: I overlooked, that the OP already wrote about this package. But according to the comments my answer seems still to be useful.)*

There is also the package doublestroke (Texlive)/dstroke (MiKTeX), which provides a serif font (and a sans-serif version), that

> is useful for typesetting the mathematical symbols for the natural numbers …, whole numbers …, rational numbers …, real numbers …, complex numbers …, and a couple of others which are sometimes needed.

To use it, one has despite the package name to add first `\usepackage{dsfont}` and later a `\mathds{<symbol>}`. There are glyphs for all capital letters A…Z, for 1, h, k and for the letter a (i.e. the *small* letter!). The latter gives a different A with the doubled line in the upstroke.

<sub>*(The source for the following example is the manual.)*</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[\mathds{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\[\mathds{a}\]
\[\mathds{1}\;\mathds{h}\;\mathds{k}\]
\end{document}
```

To get the sans-serif version, one has to set the package option ‘sans’:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[\mathds{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\[\mathds{a}\]
\[\mathds{1}\;\mathds{h}\;\mathds{k}\]
\end{document}
```

<sub>*BTW:* Found by searching with [Detexify LaTeX handwritten symbol recognition](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and then looking for `dsfont` on my computer.</sub>

Comment: I did mention the package `dsfont` in my question already, but your reply is reminding me of the fact that both its serif and its sans-serif fonts are almost there. So far I'd say this: **Serif**: The best candidates so far are `pazo` (Mathpazo bb) and `tx` (tx bb) [tie], with `px` (px bb) being a close second; I'd normally count `mathds`, but the doubling of "A" is on the wrong side from "our" expectations. **Sans-serif**: The closest candidate so far is `mathds` (with option `sans`), except the design of "Q" has a minor bug (mentioned above).

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that.

Comment: No problem! Btw, I've checked `mathds`'s `sans`-"Q" in another viewer, and there it looks fine. Hmm, it might be my version of Adobe Reader that doesn't quite render it correctly. Thus, `mathds`'s `sans` font would be an answer if the "A" has the doubled stroke on the other side.

Comment: @user14996: You could put the A into a `\scalebox{1}[-1]` (from `graphicx`) to get the stroke on the right side.

Comment: @user14996: I didn’t check it for the sans-serif version, but according to the manual you could try out `\mathds{a}` (the _small_ a!). Otherwise Caramdir’s approach.

Comment: @Speravir You're right, `\mathds{a}` works also for the `sans` version (what a surprise). Well, so I'd say the problem is solved! The winning candidate for sans-serif is thus: `\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}` with the lowercase option for "A".

Comment: (Folks, I'll mark one answer as the correct one a little bit later. I think the correct answer was found through discussion between various people, though, and I'm not entirely sure how to mark this. Any ideas? I'll check back in a couple of days later when I'm back online here.)

Comment: @user14996: You could accept one answer (which gives 15 pts. of reputation) and [set a bounty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to the other.

Comment: @Speravir Thanks for the suggestion. Except I can't ... the correct answer is just so distributed. I could write a definitive summary answer myself and vote for my own summary as the correct answer, but wouldn't that be a bit odd, community-wise?

Comment: @Caramdir I like your idea :-), except you meant `\scalebox{-1}[1]{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you can load the `\mathbb` (or `\symbb`) alphabets from any other font with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  I’m not sure exactly what you want (Is it similar to [this?](https://fersch.de/pdfdoc/Mathematik.pdf)), but here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{CDHNRQSZ} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella sample]

Here is the same sample with the font changed to:

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

[image: DejaVu Math Sample]

You might also try Microsoft’s Cambria Math, if you have it on your system.

Or for a sans-serif version, you might change the relevant line to:

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

Beware: As of 2019, `range=` and `version=` do not mix.

You can see [the list of symbols from `unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#18) for font samples of the double-struck letters from a half-dozen fonts, and look for specimens of [the rest.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)  (Note that all the most common double-struck letters, including ℂ, ℕ, ℝ and ℤ, are printed in section 13.3 instead.)

If you find a display font that is not a math font, but you like better, you can use a similar command, e.g `\setmathfont{FoglihtenNo3}[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]`.

#### Follow-up to earlier answers

[The `mathalfa` package changed its name to `mathalpha` in 2019,](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) and some of the alphabet names have changed.  The older names should continue to work.

Comment: How can I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihCuk.png) knowing that `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` results in [this](https://i.ibb.co/QXfCnWC/image.png)?

Comment: @Diaa That looks somewhat similar to TeX Gyre Dejavu Math. I could post more samples and edit down to the one that looks best.

Comment: @Diaa It’s almost identical to Cambria Math.

Comment: I away from my PC, however, you may answer my [last-asked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507673/2288) since it is about what I asked you for here.