# Are there any embossed fonts?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I there some (build in) font like:

Fluted Germanica

[image]

Shadowed Germanica

[image]

Embossed Germanica

[image]

from [Germanica family](http://www.dafont.com/germanica-family.font)

I would like use for math, so I need characters like `{` too.

Or the installing and using `.ttf` file is the only way?

Comment: I just found [effect trough pstricks or tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62570/letterpress-effect-through-pstricks-or-tikz), it could help.

Comment: There's a manual for converting fonts for use with `pdftex`: http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm
However, I would discourage you from doing so, and suggest you to switch to XeLaTeX. And you cannot use any font for math easily, for math you need dozens of dozens special tweaks for each font.

Comment: If you are limiting yourself to tex-ready fonts, you might have a look here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/.  Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters

Comment: `\mathbb{}` from the `amsfonts` package is an embossed math font, though it is not a blackletter font like Germanica. I mention it because it is not clear from your question whether you are specifically seeking blackletter fonts or merely the embossed feature.

Comment: @boucekv Have you "solved" the problem?

Comment: @masu I do not solve this. But I used this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/how-to-change-color-of-edge-of-characters instead.

Comment: @boucekv what do you think about flagging this question as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Embossed is different because the border have not constant length and its shape can vary much more. But the effect is similar enough. I can non judge it without being biased. (I prefere not to mark it as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

First see [traditional German sans-serif (and serif) blackboard-bold symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60014/traditional-german-sans-serif-and-serif-blackboard-bold-symbols). With packages `mathalfa` or `doublestroke` (TeX Live) / `dstroke` (MiKTeX) you come close to that, what you want. Similar is `\mathbb` from package `amsfonts`.

*(From comments):*

- The answers in [How to change color of edge of characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/how-to-change-color-of-edge-of-characters) and [Outlined characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters) seem to be helpful, at least in parts.
- Similar is [Letterpress effect through PSTricks or Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62570/letterpress-effect-through-pstricks-or-tikz).
- In [The LaTeX Font Catalogue – Other Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/otherfonts.html) a small number of fonts could suit to your wish, but none of them is listed in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue – Fonts with math support](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html).