# Contour text in xelatex

Tags: xetex, highlighting, contour

I have this MWE which work fine with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.2pt}

\pagecolor{blue!30}

\begin{document}

\contour{yellow}{\Huge This is a sample text}\par

\end{document}
```

How can I do the same with `xelatex`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add packages 'bidicontour' and 'bidi' (in that order) and prefix the contour macros with 'bidi':

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bidicontour}
\usepackage{bidi}

\bidicontourlength{1.2pt}
\pagecolor{blue!30}

\begin{document}
\bidicontour{yellow}{\Huge This is a sample text}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is not a solution, but a workaround.**

It seems that what `contour` does is somewhat exclusive to pdf, and apparently XeTeX does not support that. e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25221/134574), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225637/134574), [and this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354410/134574).

Apparently the way to make contours in XeTeX is to use low-level pdf commands, like the ones showed in the answers linked above (P.S.: At the time I was writing this, remco proved otherwise. Anyway...).

I merged the solutions to a few other questions and made a macro that simulates the `\contour`:

```
\fillstroke{<fill color>}{<contour color>}{<stroke width>}{<text>}
```

where `<fill color>` and `<contour color>` are valid color names, `<stroke width>` is a number, *NOT* a dimension, so no units allowed, and `<text>` is the text (wow).

Here are the macros:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\rgbtoarray#1,#2,#3\null{[#1 #2 #3]}
\def\csvtoarray#1{%
  \expandafter\rgbtoarray#1\null%
}
\newcommand{\extractrgb}[2]{%
  \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor}%
  \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{rgb}{\printcol}%
  \edef#2{\printcol}%
}
\newcommand*{\fillstroke}[4]{%
  \extractrgb{#1}{\colorvector}%
  \extractrgb{#2}{\strokevector}%
  \special{pdf:bcolor \csvtoarray{\colorvector} \csvtoarray{\strokevector}}%
  \special{pdf:literal direct #3 w 2 Tr}%
  #4%
  \special{pdf:ecolor}%
  \special{pdf:literal direct 0 Tr}%
}
```

The only required package is `xcolor`.

And here is your MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagecolor{blue!30}

\def\rgbtoarray#1,#2,#3\null{[#1 #2 #3]}
\def\csvtoarray#1{%
  \expandafter\rgbtoarray#1\null%
}
\newcommand{\extractrgb}[2]{%
  \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor}%
  \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{rgb}{\printcol}%
  \edef#2{\printcol}%
}
\newcommand*{\fillstroke}[4]{%
  \extractrgb{#1}{\colorvector}%
  \extractrgb{#2}{\strokevector}%
  \special{pdf:bcolor \csvtoarray{\colorvector} \csvtoarray{\strokevector}}%
  \special{pdf:literal direct #3 w 2 Tr}%
  #4%
  \special{pdf:ecolor}%
  \special{pdf:literal direct 0 Tr}%
}

\begin{document}

\fillstroke{black}{yellow}{0.5}{\Huge This is a sample text}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The outline produced are much nicer than those of the accepted answer. Maybe it just needs a font more adapted to the purpose, so that the outline can have a more uniform separation.

Comment: @thymaro One thing I noticed is that the outline produced by remco's answer produces an effect similar to setting a negative stroke width in my answer... Maybe the bidi package does something like this internally...

Comment: I think bidicontour prints the (yellow) outline first, and then the 'normal' text on top of that (hint: comment out the bidi packageand ignore the errors). Which means that you add an outline around the normal glyphs. With the low-level pdf commands, it looks to me you print the outline of the normal glyphs in a colour, and fill the remaining space with (here) black.

Comment: @remco Yes. The `contour` method overlaps two slightly differently-sized copies of the text (with `\rlap`) and the PDF literal method works directly on the glyphs. (I did an experiment at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464402/xelatex-and-black-outline-characters-in-devanagari/516401#516401).