# XeLaTeX and black Outline characters in Devanagari?

Tags: xetex

I'd like to make some practice worksheets for Devanagari in Outline characters but can't.

I've perused the archive and have not been successful in finding a MWE that works.

Could someone help?

TIA

Comment: Related/duplicate? [Proper outline in Devanagari and Arabic fonts](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/169636)

Comment: Agreed that it is duplicate, but that answer seems difficult to expand to general use.  Although not specifically Devanagari or Arabic fonts, [this answer: Contour text in xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421980/78866) seems both related and better.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the examples that do outlining in XeLaTeX either require `contour`, `tikz`, `pstricks`, or utilizing the `\special{}` command.  Contour doesn't seem to work for Devanagari (at least for me).  `tikz`/`pstricks` require extra processing/package loading.  And most of the examples using `\special{}` are somewhat cryptic and difficult to understand...

Luckily, I found [this answer which makes the process much easier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421980/78866), thanks to @phelype-oleinik

To make this easier for future users, I've taken the outlining (for XeLaTeX) in the link above and combined the use of `polyglossia` to show examples of outlining Devanagari.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\hindifont[Scale=MatchUppercase,Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hindi}


\usepackage{xcolor}

%SEE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421980/78866
%for explanation and usage

\def\rgbtoarray#1,#2,#3\null{[#1 #2 #3]}%
\def\csvtoarray#1{%
    \expandafter\rgbtoarray#1\null%
}%
\newcommand{\extractrgb}[2]{%
    \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor}%
    \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{rgb}{\printcol}%
    \edef#2{\printcol}%
}%
%\fillstroke{<fill color>}{<contour color>}{<stroke width>}{<text>}
\newcommand*{\fillstroke}[4]{%
    \extractrgb{#1}{\colorvector}%
    \extractrgb{#2}{\strokevector}%
    \special{pdf:bcolor \csvtoarray{\colorvector} \csvtoarray{\strokevector}}%
    \special{pdf:literal direct #3 w 2 Tr}%
    #4%
    \special{pdf:ecolor}%
    \special{pdf:literal direct 0 Tr}%
}%


\begin{document}

%Example of default
\foreignlanguage{hindi}{चीनी} (cheenee)

%Black text, yellow outline, 0.5 (outline) thickness
\fillstroke{black}{yellow}{0.5}{\Huge \foreignlanguage{hindi}{चीनी}}%

%White text, black outline, 0.5 (outline) thickness
\fillstroke{white}{black}{0.5}{\Huge \foreignlanguage{hindi}{चीनी}}%

%Black text, red outline, 0.75 (outline) thickness
\fillstroke{black}{red}{0.75}{\Huge \foreignlanguage{hindi}{चीनी}}%

%Red text, green outline, 0.25 (outline) thickness
\fillstroke{red}{green}{0.25}{\Huge \foreignlanguage{hindi}{चीनी}}%

%Blue text, gray outline, 1.5 (outline) thickness
\fillstroke{blue}{gray}{1.5}{\Huge \foreignlanguage{hindi}{चीनी}}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Examples of outlining Devanagari in XeLaTeX]

EDIT:
I'm using Noto Sans Devanagari in this example.  You should be able to replace this font with whatever font you are using already.  No other changes should be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Outlining with `contour` in xelatex can be done by not using the `outline` option. Paradox! A thin-enough contour can appear as an outline -

[image: outline]

here, detail of yellow outline with some blue `shadowtext` as well.

[image: examples]

Visual artefacts in that last example are a result of the image capture process, not the PDF viewer:

[image: dark outline]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Scale=3]
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{shadowtext}

\newcommand\sampletext{कूल्बनन}
\newcommand\sampletextb{कूल्बनन}
\newcommand\sampletextc{कूल्बनन}
\newcommand\ftcname{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontface\ftc{\ftcname}[Scale=2,Script=Devanagari]

\begin{document}
\contourlength{1.4pt}
\shadowcolor{blue}
\shadowoffsetx{1.52pt}
\shadowoffsety{1.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[32]{yellow}{%
\ftc\sampletext
}%
}%

\bigskip\medskip

\contourlength{0.4pt}
\color{yellow}
\shadowcolor{blue}
\shadowoffsetx{0.52pt}
\shadowoffsety{0.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[24]{red}{%
\ftc\sampletextb
}%
}%

\bigskip\medskip

\contourlength{0.8pt}
\color{Magenta}
\shadowcolor{blue!40}
\shadowoffsetx{4.52pt}
\shadowoffsety{2.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[24]{red}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
}%

\bigskip\medskip

\contourlength{1.2pt}
\color{White}
\shadowcolor{blue!20}
\shadowoffsetx{2.12pt}
\shadowoffsety{1.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[14]{red}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
}%

\bigskip\medskip

\contourlength{1.2pt}
\color{White}
\shadowcolor{blue!20}
\shadowoffsetx{2.12pt}
\shadowoffsety{1.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[1]{red}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
}%

\bigskip\medskip

\contourlength{2.2pt}
\color{green!15}
\shadowcolor{blue!20}
\shadowoffsetx{2.12pt}
\shadowoffsety{1.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[1]{black!12}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
}%

\bigskip\medskip

\contourlength{0.6pt}
\color{green!15}
\shadowcolor{blue!20}
\shadowoffsetx{2.12pt}
\shadowoffsety{1.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[48]{black!80}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
}%
```

`contour` uses ps commands in its driver `.cnt` files but, since it is from 2004, it hasn't been set up (yet) to detect xelatex and assign the appropriate driver to do "real" outlines with that engine. It should be straightforward enough to add the `\special`s in, though.

---

**Edited to add**:

For outline mode in `contour` package to work under xelatex, four changes are required --

Contour

The purpose of the `contour` package (last updated in 2004) is to make text more legible when printed on a variegated  background such as an image or graph. It does this by overlapping (`\rlap`) copies of the text onto itself, slightly offset by a small factor, for a distance defined by `\contourlength{}`. A consequence is that, for small values of `\contourlength{}`, say 0.6pt, the contouring effect looks like an outline of the text.

There are two ways it does the contouring or halo effect: the default method, using *cos* and *sin* smoothed over a number of iterations ('copies') to calculate the text offset (used by `\hskip` and `\raisebox`); or, alternatively, the outline method (specified by the `outline` package option), relying on low-level driver-specific commands to shift the text (by a factor of 0.99626400996) and deal with the colours. For outline mode, there is nothing for xelatex ('copies' mode in xelatex works OK).

There are several drivers defined in corresponding control files: `dvips.cnt`, which issues postscript commands via `\special{}`: `\special{ps: gsave newpath...`; 
`dvipsone.cnt`, which also does postscript: `\special{ps: gsave currentpoint newpath...`; `pdftex.cnt`, which does pdfliterals:

```
    \pdfliteral{%
      q
      1 j
      1 J
      1 Tr
      \strip@pt\con@length\space w
    }%
    \rlap{#2}%
    \pdfliteral{%
      Q
    }%
```

and `vtex.cnt`, which does another sort of postscript: `\special{pS: save newpath...`.

A config file, `contour.cfg`, takes care of detecting which driver should be used when `outline` mode is active.

So, to make `contour`'s `outline` mode work under xelatex requires the following:

(1) Define a new driver

Copy `pdftex.cnt` and rename it, say, `xdvipdfmx.cnt`. We'll use the same pdf operators.

Change `\pdfliteral{%` to `\special{pdf:literal direct`, so that we have:

```
    \special{pdf:literal direct q 1 j 1 J 2 Tr \strip@pt\con@length\space w}
    \rlap{#2}%
    \special{pdf:literal direct Q}%
```

Acknowledgement: [Outlined characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters)

(2) Add xetex detection to the existing tests in `contour.cfg`:

Insert

```
  % check xetex
  \@ifundefined{XeTeXversion}{}{%
      \chardef\x=3 % <========== setting value to next available value
    }%
```

and amend the internal-option setting to include a new `xetex` option in the case statement:

```
\ifcase\x
  % default case
  \ExecuteOptions{dvips}%
\or
  % pdfTeX is running in pdf mode
  \ExecuteOptions{pdftex}%
\or
  % VTeX is running
  \ExecuteOptions{vtex}%
\or
  % xetex
  \ExecuteOptions{xetex}%<============= 3rd
\else
  % VTeX is running
  \ExecuteOptions{vtex}%
\fi
```

(3) In `contour.sty`, one line needs to be added: declare that new `xetex` option and what it does (sets the driver name to `xdvipdfmx.cnt`).

```
\DeclareOption{xetex}{\def\con@driver{xdvipdfmx.cnt}} %<=============
```

Full files in case I've missed anything:

`xdvipdfmx.cnt`:

```
%%
%% This is file `pdftex.cnt',xxx
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% contour.dtx  (with options: `drv,pdftex')
%% 
%%   contour package driver file
%% 
%%   Copyright  2004 Harald Harders
%% 
%%   This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%%   of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
%%   archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
%%   version 1 of the License, or any later version.
%% 
%%   h.harders@tu-bs.de
%% 
\ProvidesFile{dvipdfmx.cnt}
  [2004/11/18  v2.14  Print contoured text (HH, MH); modified 2019-11-15 for xelatex]
\newcommand*\@contour@outline[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength\con@length{2\con@length}%
    \setlength\con@length{0.99626400996\con@length}%
    \color{#1}%
    \con@coloroff%===
%    \pdfliteral{%
%      q
%      1 j
%      1 J
%      1 Tr
%      \strip@pt\con@length\space w
%    }%
%%      - Tr %text rendering mode: 
%               0 fill text
%               1 stroke text
%               2 fill, then stroke text
%               3 neither fill nor stroke (invisible)
%               4 fill, add to clipping path
%               5 stroke, add to clipping path
%%      - w % width in big points
%%      - - - RG %rgb stroking colour 0-1 0-1 0-1
%%      - - - rg %rgb non-stroking colour 0-1 0-1 0-1
%%      - j %line join style
%%          0 miter (like picture frame)
%%          1 round (like arc, pie-slice)
%%          2 bevel 
%%      - J %line cap style 
%%          0   butt
%%          1   round
%%          2   projecting square
%%          
%%      - w %line width
%%      q %save current graphics state
%%      Q %restore graphics state
    \special{pdf:literal direct q 1 j 1 J 2 Tr      \strip@pt\con@length\space w}
    \rlap{#2}%
%    \pdfliteral{%
%      Q
%    }%
    \special{pdf:literal direct Q}%
  \endgroup
  \mbox{#2}%
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `xdvipdfmx.cnt'.
```

`contour.cfg`:

```
%%
%% This is file `contour.cfg',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% contour.dtx  (with options: `cfgfile')
%% -
%%   contour package configuration file
%% 
%%   Copyright  2004 Harald Harders
%% 
%%   This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%%   of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
%%   archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
%%   version 1 of the License, or any later version.
%% 
%%   h.harders@tu-bs.de
%% 
\ProvidesFile{contour.cfg}
  [2004/11/18  v2.14  Print contoured text (HH, MH); modified 2019-11-16 for xetex ]
 % Select an appropriate default driver
\begingroup
  \chardef\x=0 %
  % check pdftex
  \@ifundefined{pdfoutput}{}{%
    \ifcase\pdfoutput
    \else
      \chardef\x=1 %
    \fi
  }%
  % check VTeX
  \@ifundefined{OpMode}{}{%
    \chardef\x=2 %
  }%
  % check xetex
  \@ifundefined{XeTeXversion}{}{%
      \chardef\x=3 % 
    }%
%%  \ifxetex %requires ifxetex package
%%      \chardef\x=3 %
%%  \fi
\expandafter\endgroup
\ifcase\x
  % default case
  \ExecuteOptions{dvips}%
\or
  % pdfTeX is running in pdf mode
  \ExecuteOptions{pdftex}%
\or
  % VTeX is running
  \ExecuteOptions{vtex}%
\or
  % xetex
  \ExecuteOptions{xetex}%
\else
  % VTeX is running
  \ExecuteOptions{vtex}%
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `contour.cfg'.
```

`contour.sty`:

```
%%
%% This is file `contour.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% contour.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%%   contour package
%% 
%%   Copyright  1999--2004 Harald Harders, Morten H�gholm
%% 
%%   This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%%   of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
%%   archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
%%   version 1 of the License, or any later version.
%% 
%%   h.harders@tu-bs.de, moho01ab@student.cbs.dk
%% 
%% 
%%   Original: Richard Pfeiffer (richard.pfeiffer@t-online.de)
%%   Totally rewritten end extended.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{contour}
  [2004/11/18  v2.14  Print contoured text (HH, MH); modified 2019-11-16 for xetex]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}%<=========== changed from color to xcolor
\RequirePackage{trig}
%%\RequirePackage{ifxetex}%xxx for \ifxetex command
\def\con@coloroff{%
  \def\@undeclaredcolor[##1]##2{}%
  \def\@declaredcolor##1{}%
}
\newcommand*\con@put[3]{%
  \rlap{\hskip#1\raisebox{#2}[0pt]{#3}}%
}
\newcommand*\contourlength[1]{\def\con@base@length{#1}}
\contourlength{0.03em}
\newcommand*\contournumber[1]{\def\con@default@copies{#1}}
\contournumber{16}
\newlength{\con@length}
\newcommand*\con@define@copyangles[1]{%
  \edef\con@tempa{auto}%
  \edef\con@tempb{#1}%
  \ifx\con@tempa\con@tempb
    \expandafter\ifdim\f@size pt<15pt\relax
      \edef\con@tempb{16}%
    \else
      \expandafter\ifdim\f@size pt<25pt\relax
        \edef\con@tempb{32}%
      \else
        \expandafter\ifdim\f@size pt<50pt\relax
          \edef\con@tempb{60}%
        \else
          \edef\con@tempb{120}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \@tempcnta=\con@tempb\relax
  \@ifundefined{con@\number\@tempcnta @copies}{%
    \global\@namedef{con@\number\@tempcnta @copies}{}%
    \@tempdima=360\p@
    \divide\@tempdima by \@tempcnta
    \@tempdimb=\z@
    \@tempcntb=\z@
    \loop
      \ifnum\@tempcntb<\@tempcnta
        \edef\con@temp@fdim{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
        \CalculateSin{\con@temp@fdim}%
        \CalculateCos{\con@temp@fdim}%
        \advance\@tempcntb \@ne
        \advance\@tempdimb \@tempdima\relax
    \repeat
  }{}%
  \let\con@tempa\@undefined
  \let\con@tempb\@undefined
}
\newcommand*\contour{\@ifstar{\@contour[32]}{\@contour}}
\newcommand*\@contour[3][\con@default@copies]{%
  \ifvmode
    \leavevmode
  \fi
  \setlength\con@length{\con@base@length}%
  \ifcon@outline
    \typeout{contour: Using real outline for `#3'\on@line.}%
    \@contour@outline{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \begingroup
      \con@define@copyangles{#1}%
      \typeout{contour: Using \the\@tempcnta\space copies for `#3'\on@line.}%
      \@tempdima=360\p@
      \divide\@tempdima by \@tempcnta\relax
      \@tempdimb=\z@
      \@tempcntb=\z@
      \color{#2}%
      \con@coloroff
      \loop
        \ifnum\@tempcntb<\@tempcnta\relax
          \edef\con@temp@fdim{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
          \con@put
            {\UseSin{\con@temp@fdim}\con@length}%
            {\UseCos{\con@temp@fdim}\con@length}%
            {#3}%
          \advance\@tempcntb \@ne\relax
          \advance\@tempdimb\@tempdima\relax
      \repeat
    \endgroup
    \mbox{#3}%
  \fi
}
\providecommand*\con@driver{\@empty}
\newif\ifcon@outline
\DeclareOption{auto}{\contournumber{auto}}
\DeclareOption{dvips}{\def\con@driver{dvips.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{xdvi}{\ExecuteOptions{dvips}}
\DeclareOption{pdftex}{\def\con@driver{pdftex.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{xetex}{\def\con@driver{xdvipdfmx.cnt}} %<=============
\DeclareOption{vtex}{\def\con@driver{vtex.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{dvipsone}{\def\con@driver{dvipsone.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{outline}{\con@outlinetrue}
\DeclareOption{copies}{\con@outlinefalse}
\InputIfFileExists{contour.cfg}{%
  \typeout{Loading configuration file `contour.cfg'.}%
}{%
  \typeout{No configuration file `contour.cfg' found.}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\expandafter\ifx\con@driver\@empty
  \ifcon@outline
    \PackageError{contour}{Chosen package option `outline' but no
      driver defined}{Leave out the `outline' option or define a driver}%
  \else
    \PackageWarning{contour}{No driver defined (which does not matter
      when using copies)}%
  \fi
\else
  \InputIfFileExists{\con@driver}{%
    \typeout{contour: Using driver file `\con@driver'.}%
  }{%
    \PackageError{contour}{Driver file `\con@driver' does not exist}{}%
  }%
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `contour.sty'.
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\newcommand\sampletextc{कूल्बनन}
\newcommand\ftcname{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontface\ftc{\ftcname}[Scale=2,Script=Devanagari]

\begin{document}

\contourlength{1pt}
\color{white}
\Huge
\contour{black}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
\end{document}
```

End result:

outline mode:

[image: contours outline method with xelatex]

For comparison, the copies mode at the same settings:

[image: contour copies mode with xelatex]

Perhaps there might be a way to officially update the package, if the outline mode  under xelatex is deemed useful enough (and later, when lualatex's font-shaping engine can shape complex non-latin syllables correctly, also under lualatex). As a fallback, kerning (on an overlap) can always be done manually.

*Note*

There is some confusion about the meaning of "outline" when `contour` package uses the term: `outline` means "widen an *outline font* by using the `w` PDF operator so as to produce the underlying text to `rlap` onto the unshifted text".

It does not mean "colour the outer edge of the glyph shape".

In both of these examples below, the blue-coloured text is underneath and is wider than the yellow-coloured text on top. Both of the examples are produced using the `outline` option. It's just that the "halo" (the blue part) is quite narrow in the second example, and gives the illusion that it is the yellow text that has been converted to an "outline".

[image: is it outlined text]

Commenting out the `\rlap` command shows how the "outlining" is done:

[image: the effect is done by overlapping text]

---

**Edited to further add**:

Looks like the PDF operators can handle stroke width, stroke colour, and fill colour. No need for overlapping anything.

Breaking away somewhat from the spirit of the `contour` package (which is to add a background halo following the contours of the glyphs) -

Added a new option `xeoutline` which does "true" outlines under xelatex (and no need for overlapping), using PDF stroke and fill operations, with new commands  `\cfillrgb{}{}{}` defining the three-channel RGB fill colour (values go from 0-1), `\cstrokergb{}{}{}` defining the RGB stroke colour, and `\cstrokewidth{}` setting the stroke width (in big points, apparently). The first parameter of `\contour` becomes superfluous under `xeoutline` option and can be left empty (or non-empty, it doesn't go anywhere).

e.g.

```
\cfillrgb{1}{0.75}{1}%purple-y mauve
\cstrokergb{.3}{0.85}{0.5}%dark greeny
\cstrokewidth{1.6}%big points: thick line
\contour{}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
```

produces

[image: thich-line output]

There is a new `xdvipdfmx2.cnt` file

```
%%
%% This is file `pdftex.cnt',xxx
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% contour.dtx  (with options: `drv,pdftex')
%% 
%%   contour package driver file
%% 
%%   Copyright  2004 Harald Harders
%% 
%%   This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%%   of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
%%   archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
%%   version 1 of the License, or any later version.
%% 
%%   h.harders@tu-bs.de
%% 
\ProvidesFile{dvipdfmx2.cnt}
  [2004/11/18  v2.14  Print contoured text (HH, MH); modified 2019-11-17 for xelatex and `real' outlines]
\newcommand*\@contour@outline[2]{%
  \begingroup
%    \setlength\con@length{2\con@length}%
%    \setlength\con@length{0.99626400996\con@length}%
%    \color{#1}%
%    \con@coloroff%===
%    \pdfliteral{%
%      q
%      1 j
%      1 J
%      1 Tr
%      \strip@pt\con@length\space w
%    }%
%%      - Tr %text rendering mode: 
%               0 fill text
%               1 stroke text
%               2 fill, then stroke text
%               3 neither fill nor stroke (invisible)
%               4 fill, add to clipping path
%               5 stroke, add to clipping path
%%      - w % width in big points
%%      - - - RG %rgb stroking colour 0-1 0-1 0-1
%%      - - - rg %rgb non-stroking colour 0-1 0-1 0-1
%%      - j %line join style
%%          0 miter (like picture frame)
%%          1 round (like arc, pie-slice)
%%          2 bevel 
%%      - J %line cap style 
%%          0   butt
%%          1   round
%%          2   projecting square
%%          
%%      - w %line width
%%      q %save current graphics state
%%      Q %restore graphics state
    \special{pdf:literal direct q 1 j 1 J 2 Tr %\strip@pt\con@length\space w
    \pdfls\space RG \pdflf\space rg \cswidth\space w 2 Tr}
    {#2}%
%    \pdfliteral{%
%      Q
%    }%
    \special{pdf:literal direct Q}%
  \endgroup
%
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `xdvipdfmx2.cnt'.
```

and a modified `contour.sty` file

```
%%
%% This is file `contour.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% contour.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%%   contour package
%% 
%%   Copyright  1999--2004 Harald Harders, Morten H�gholm
%% 
%%   This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%%   of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
%%   archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
%%   version 1 of the License, or any later version.
%% 
%%   h.harders@tu-bs.de, moho01ab@student.cbs.dk
%% 
%% 
%%   Original: Richard Pfeiffer (richard.pfeiffer@t-online.de)
%%   Totally rewritten end extended.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{contour}
  [2004/11/18  v2.14  Print contoured text (HH, MH); modified 2019-11-16 for xetex, 2019-11-17 `real' outlines added]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}%<=========== changed from color to xcolor
\RequirePackage{trig}
%%\RequirePackage{ifxetex}%xxx for \ifxetex command
\def\con@coloroff{%
  \def\@undeclaredcolor[##1]##2{}%
  \def\@declaredcolor##1{}%
}
\newcommand*\con@put[3]{%
  \rlap{\hskip#1\raisebox{#2}[0pt]{#3}}%
}
\newcommand*\contourlength[1]{\def\con@base@length{#1}}
\contourlength{0.03em}
\newcommand*\contournumber[1]{\def\con@default@copies{#1}}
\contournumber{16}
\newlength{\con@length}
\newcommand*\con@define@copyangles[1]{%
  \edef\con@tempa{auto}%
  \edef\con@tempb{#1}%
  \ifx\con@tempa\con@tempb
    \expandafter\ifdim\f@size pt<15pt\relax
      \edef\con@tempb{16}%
    \else
      \expandafter\ifdim\f@size pt<25pt\relax
        \edef\con@tempb{32}%
      \else
        \expandafter\ifdim\f@size pt<50pt\relax
          \edef\con@tempb{60}%
        \else
          \edef\con@tempb{120}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \@tempcnta=\con@tempb\relax
  \@ifundefined{con@\number\@tempcnta @copies}{%
    \global\@namedef{con@\number\@tempcnta @copies}{}%
    \@tempdima=360\p@
    \divide\@tempdima by \@tempcnta
    \@tempdimb=\z@
    \@tempcntb=\z@
    \loop
      \ifnum\@tempcntb<\@tempcnta
        \edef\con@temp@fdim{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
        \CalculateSin{\con@temp@fdim}%
        \CalculateCos{\con@temp@fdim}%
        \advance\@tempcntb \@ne
        \advance\@tempdimb \@tempdima\relax
    \repeat
  }{}%
  \let\con@tempa\@undefined
  \let\con@tempb\@undefined
}
\newcommand*\contour{\@ifstar{\@contour[32]}{\@contour}}
\newcommand*\@contour[3][\con@default@copies]{%
  \ifvmode
    \leavevmode
  \fi
  \setlength\con@length{\con@base@length}%
  \ifcon@outline
    \typeout{contour: Using real outline for `#3'\on@line.}%
    \@contour@outline{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \begingroup
      \con@define@copyangles{#1}%
      \typeout{contour: Using \the\@tempcnta\space copies for `#3'\on@line.}%
      \@tempdima=360\p@
      \divide\@tempdima by \@tempcnta\relax
      \@tempdimb=\z@
      \@tempcntb=\z@
      \color{#2}%
      \con@coloroff
      \loop
        \ifnum\@tempcntb<\@tempcnta\relax
          \edef\con@temp@fdim{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
          \con@put
            {\UseSin{\con@temp@fdim}\con@length}%
            {\UseCos{\con@temp@fdim}\con@length}%
            {#3}%
          \advance\@tempcntb \@ne\relax
          \advance\@tempdimb\@tempdima\relax
      \repeat
    \endgroup
    \mbox{#3}%
  \fi
}
\providecommand*\con@driver{\@empty}
\newif\ifcon@outline
\DeclareOption{auto}{\contournumber{auto}}
\DeclareOption{dvips}{\def\con@driver{dvips.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{xdvi}{\ExecuteOptions{dvips}}
\DeclareOption{pdftex}{\def\con@driver{pdftex.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{xetex}{\def\con@driver{xdvipdfmx.cnt}} %<=============
\DeclareOption{vtex}{\def\con@driver{vtex.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{dvipsone}{\def\con@driver{dvipsone.cnt}}
\DeclareOption{outline}{\con@outlinetrue}
\DeclareOption{copies}{\con@outlinefalse}
\DeclareOption{xeoutline}{\con@outlinetrue\def\con@driver{xdvipdfmx2.cnt}} %<============2
\InputIfFileExists{contour.cfg}{%
  \typeout{Loading configuration file `contour.cfg'.}%
}{%
  \typeout{No configuration file `contour.cfg' found.}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\expandafter\ifx\con@driver\@empty
  \ifcon@outline
    \PackageError{contour}{Chosen package option `outline' but no
      driver defined}{Leave out the `outline' option or define a driver}%
  \else
    \PackageWarning{contour}{No driver defined (which does not matter
      when using copies)}%
  \fi
\else
  \InputIfFileExists{\con@driver}{%
    \typeout{contour: Using driver file `\con@driver'.}%
  }{%
    \PackageError{contour}{Driver file `\con@driver' does not exist}{}%
  }%
\fi
%<============2: new adds
%colour: stroke: set:
\newcommand\cstrokergb[3]{\edef\pdfls{#1\space #2\space  #3\space }}
\cstrokergb{1}{0}{0}%default = red
%colour: fill: set:
\newcommand\cfillrgb[3]{\edef\pdflf{#1\space #2\space  #3\space }}
\cfillrgb{0}{1}{1}%default = cyan
%stroke: width: set
\newcommand\cstrokewidth[1]{\edef\cswidth{#1\space}}
\cstrokewidth{0.3}%default (unit=big points?)
%<============2 end new adds
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `contour.sty'.
```

No change in the `contour.cfg` file.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xeoutline]{contour}

\newcommand\sampletextc{कूल्बनन}
\newcommand\ftcname{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontface\ftc{\ftcname}[Scale=2,Script=Devanagari]

\begin{document}

\Huge

\contour{}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
\bigskip

%\contourlength{8.6pt}
%\color{yellow}
\cfillrgb{1}{1}{0}%yellow
\cstrokergb{0}{0}{1}%blue
\cstrokewidth{3.6}%big points
\contour{}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
\bigskip

\cfillrgb{1}{1}{1}%white
\cstrokergb{0}{0}{0}%black
\cstrokewidth{0.6}%big points
\contour{}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
\bigskip

\cfillrgb{.95}{.95}{.95}%off-white
\cstrokergb{.1}{.1}{.1}%off-black
\cstrokewidth{0.6}%big points
\contour{}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
\bigskip

\cfillrgb{1}{0.75}{1}%purple-y mauve
\cstrokergb{.3}{0.85}{0.5}%dark greeny
\cstrokewidth{1.6}%big points: thick line
\contour{}{%
\ftc\sampletextc
}%
\bigskip


\end{document}
```

[image: output from MWE]

Outside the `xeoutline` option, normal `contour` functions continue as usual (plus `contour`'s overlapping `outline` option now works under xelatex).

Comment: And it is only now that I begin to understand @PhelypeOleinik 's workaround code at 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421980/78866 , which is much more compact and elegant (and uses `xcolor`'s colour conversion macros as well, like the first answer too).