# LuaTeX/PdfTeX: Incorrect transparency for fonts with overlapping glyphs -- achieve effect similar to Adobe InDesign/Tikz in text mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex, pdf, transparency

> **Update-1:** This issue affects all fonts that assume glyph overlap. The 3 broad categories affected are: 1) All fonts for non-Latin scripts that inherently require glyph overlap, 2) Handwriting (cursive) fonts for Latin script, 3) Decoration fonts meant to build complex decorations (like decorative borders/frames) by repeating patterns of glyphs that partially overlap.

> **Update-2: *This question has not been answered yet.*** After [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton) posted [this ‘related answer’ below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565470/192717), the correct understanding is that tikz "transparency group" does apply grouped transparency to node text too. The mistake in my tikz code was that I invoked transparency grouping, but specified opacity at a different scope level. I have updated my original code in question, and tikz output looks good. This means the code needed for transparency grouping in text mode (outside tikz) can be either adapted from tikz codebase, or written by someone who understands `PDF XObjects`. It is fine even if transparency is applied only to latex's  unbreakable boxes like package `textpos`‘s environment `texblock` or `minipage`, or plain tex's boxes (`vbox` and `hbox`); that itself will be a big leap. Someone who understands macro `\pdfxform` from [section 8.8 of pdftex user manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex?lang=en) might be able to help.

In some scripts it is almost impossible to have non-overlapping glyph components. Thats either because some complex glyphs are themselves composed of multiple -- potentially overlapping -- component glyphs, or by design adjacent glyphs need to overlap to form a word. Both are true for Devanagari, with the latter due to the fact that "overline" of glyphs in a word has to overlap to make it a word (its a script feature in addition to inter-word spacing). These overlaps are (rightly) not visible when text is set in a solid color, and are visible when it is set in a transparent one.

Setting `fontspec` Opacity for such scripts produces ugly result (making it unusable), see for instance the following image that is Hindi word for male parent (पिताजी) set with Opacity. As you can see, Opacity setting results in darker spots at overlapping areas. This is because text is not grouped before applying transparency (Opacity setting applies transparency at individual glyph level). Tikz doesn't have this problem if one uses its implicit or explicit transparency grouping (tikz output not shown here, it can be seen by compiling code in this question). Below fontspec `Opacity` output is the output from Adobe InDesign 2020 (I luckily still had access to trial version of InDesign) which looks great (no dark spots on overlap, and result looks uniform). I tested the output of text transparency grouping from both Tikz and Adobe InDesign, text is not converted to path upon grouping (text is copyable/searchable, which is great). From [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton)'s [analysis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565470/192717) Tikz and Adobe InDesign produce similar PDF code.

LuaLaTeX with `fontspec` and `Opacity<1` output:
[image: LuaLaTeX output: It has darker areas where glyphs overlap]

Adobe InDesign 2020 output:
[image: Adobe InDesign output: It doesn't have darker areas where glyphs overlap]
An ideal solution will perform grouped transparency in **text mode** (its ok if it just works with HarfBuzz), like the way "transparency groups" work for tikz text and graphics. The text should still act like text in pdf, it should be searchable & copyable, and should not add any restrictions in text mode (such transparent text can span paragraphs, etc). If it makes it easier to implement, a solution could restrict itself to applying grouped transparency to package `textpos`'s environment `textblock` or `minipage` such that all objects within that environment will be part of transparency group (potentially with a parameter for blend mode, and potentially groups can be nested just like tikz transparency groups, and color commands `\color/\textcolor` [though nesting would be an added bonus, not the most important]).  ***As a side note, am not looking for a tikz solution (that acts similar to textpos or minipage with grouped transparency), though you are welcome to post a solution that does that for the broader community here (with first line explicitly stating in bold that "This is not a solution to this question, and is being posted here only to showcase what can be achieved with tikz.").[1]***

[1] It might sound too strict, but IMO an incorrect answer that seems to partially solve the question might not invite further inquiry/drive towards a correct solution.

As a reference, the screenshot below from [Section 17.3.1 of asppdf manual](http://www.asppdf.com/manual_17.html) could lead us to a solution. It looks like the solution for the problem in this question would need to implement a transparency grouping like in the bottom-left figure in screenshot. The paragraphs above the four transparency grouping images explain things pretty well. The current transparency implementation functions like top-right image (transparency with no grouping, causing glyphs to composite with each other).

[image: Image showing different transparency grouping options]

Here's the test code to regenerate the problem of dark areas at overlap. You might have to zoom-in to see the problem on screen, but it will be glaringly visible & distracting in a printed document. Lastly, this is **not a font issue**, and can be recreated with any existing Devanagari font.

```latex
% >> lualatex opacityoverlap.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newfontfamily{\devanagarifamtext}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1, Renderer=HarfBuzz, Color=FF0000, Opacity=0.25]

\newfontfamily{\devanagarifamtikz}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1, Renderer=HarfBuzz, Color=FF0000]

\begin{document}

Text mode: {\devanagarifamtext एक गांव में पिताजी}

Tikz mode: \tikz[baseline,blend group=hue,opacity=0.25]{\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum width=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=base] () {\devanagarifamtikz एक गांव में पिताजी};}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ConTeXt has the same problem, just fyi even though am not looking for a ConTeXt solution. Compiling the same code above with xelatex gives the same result, also just fyi even though am not looking for a xetex solution either. A solution would compile good output with lualatex, I mention pdftex in name as luatex is based on it and perhaps a solution can be inspired from there.

Comment: `fontspec` option `Opacity` eventually writes `/ca` entry to output PDF. Apparently inserting `/BM` to set blend mode, either by `tikz` or primitives is a workaround. Can you provide the output PDF from Adobe InDesign 2020, so that people here can dig into it and possibly find other workarounds?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Here we go... The PDF has just two things in it: 1) Semi-transparent text string `पिताजी`, 2) A semi-transparent circle behind text. It is uncompressed too (you can open it directly in a text editor). Link to PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hn-msdyAf605oEiDzUufNDuhOn_ta6Vh/view?usp=sharing, Link to InDesign file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUcHVyaSIhBrfMR746nvyXct2HvzNG_w/view?usp=sharing. Maybe transparency groups are done with `Transparency/Type/Group` in PDF (idk). Fyi, InDesign reverses order of `प` & ` ि` , so just use part `ताजी` as a pdf test search string.

Comment: Potentially related: if the question is about the difference between 'stroke' and 'fill', an alternative workaround could be "outlining" the characters instead (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464402/xelatex-and-black-outline-characters-in-devanagari/464446#464446).

Comment: The logo on the title page of the `microtype` manual uses blend mode inside a graphic state inside a form object: all the right ingredients -- `\immediate\pdfobj{<</Type/ExtGState /CA 0.6 /ca 0.6 /BM/Normal >>}%
\immediate\pdfxform
attr {/Group <</Type/Group /S/Transparency /I true /CS/DeviceRGB >>}
resources {/Properties <<\mtl@resources>>
/ExtGState << /SXS \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R >> }
\logobox`

Comment: adobe reader handles the text example much better, there I see only one small overlap. So it is also a pdf viewer issue.

Comment: Yes, even with stroke and fill set to the same colour and opacity=0.25, in some text rendering modes (`2 Tr` = fill, then stroke text, and `4 Tr` = fill, add to clipping path), adobe reader is different (no overlaps) to TeXworks pdf viewer (overlaps).

Comment: @Cicada: Given those macros are not available in luatex, I tried this from the manual: \directlua{
  local n = pdf.immediateobj("<</Type/ExtGState /CA 0.6 /ca 0.6 /BM/Normal >>");
  local index = tex.saveboxresources(n,"{/Group <</Type/Group /S/Transparency /I true /CS/DeviceRGB >>}", "/Properties <<\luaescapestring{\mtl@resources}>> /ExtGState << /SXS \luaescapestring{\the\pdflastobj\space} 0 R >>",true);
} \logobox. Though it fails with undefined control sequence...

Comment: @reportaman Look in `microtype-logo.dtx`, it has 400+ lines of code and is included as an attachment in the manual (texdoc microtype). It provides the single command `\printlogo`.

Comment: @reportaman For TikZ code, look in `pgfsys-common-pdf.def`. It defines the various relevant commands (e.g., `% Blending
\def\pgfsys@blend@mode#1{% ...`) and corresponding pdf literals formatting (e.g., `<< /BM [ /\pgf@temp ] >>`).

Comment: All three, pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex, can inject pdf specials/literals into the output stream, so the solution space would be much bigger than just with lua code (or expl3 code) although code would be handy and could be developed into a package. But TikZ has already done that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is not a solution to this question, and is being posted here only to showcase what can be achieved with tikz/pgf** (as instructed in question).

### Update: PGF only answer

Here's an optimised solution using only `pgf`. It has less overhead than using the `tikz` interface. Having looked at this for too long, I think this is the best solution by a long way. It's much simpler to implement, works with other packages, and has a minimal speed hit.

Blend modes seem unreliable across viewers unless you're careful how you lay out your text in the `pgfpicture`, so I don't think there's anything to be gained by using them.

```
%! TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgf}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment { transparencygroup }
  { m +b }
  {
    \par
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_dim \prevdepth
    \noindent
    \pgfrememberpicturepositiononpagefalse
    \begin { pgfpicture }
      \pgfsetfillopacity { #1 }
      \begin { pgftransparencygroup } [ isolated=false ]
        \pgfpathmoveto { \pgfpointorigin }
        \pgftext [ base ]
          {
            \vbox:n
              {
                \dim_set_eq:NN \prevdepth \l_tmpa_dim
                #2
              }
          }
      \end { pgftransparencygroup }
    \end { pgfpicture }
  }
  { }

\NewDocumentCommand \texttransparencygroup { m m }
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \hbox:n
      {
        \pgfrememberpicturepositiononpagefalse
        \begin { pgfpicture }
          \pgfsetfillopacity { #1 }
          \begin { pgftransparencygroup } [ isolated=true ]
            \pgfpathmoveto { \pgfpointorigin }
            \pgftext [ base ] { #2 }
          \end { pgftransparencygroup }
        \end { pgfpicture }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\devanagari}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari, Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\begin{document}

\Huge
English {\devanagari \texttransparencygroup{0.4}{एक गांव में पिताजी}} English

\devanagari\color{red}
\begin{transparencygroup}{0.5}
  एक गांव में पिताजी
\end{transparencygroup}

\vskip-8mm
\color{green}
\begin{transparencygroup}{0.25}
  एक गांव में पिताजी
\end{transparencygroup}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

### TIKZ answer

Your PDF from InDesign is essentially using the same method as tikz. It creates a Form XObject with a transparency group and puts the text in it. Then it inserts this Form XObject into the Page stream. Even if you don't use tikz you'll still have to box your content up into an XObject. The transparency group isn't just a graphics flag you can turn on and off mid-stream.

The trick with `tikz` seems to be to put just the text in the transparency group:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{l3pdf}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \pdf_uncompress:
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \newfontfamily{\devanagari}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1, Renderer=HarfBuzz]
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.5]
      \fill[cyan] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
      \begin{scope}[transparency group]
        \node[text=red, font=\devanagari] {एक गांव में पिताजी};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: output]

Here's a fuller example, showing how to put a couple of paragraphs of different colours in a transparency group. It also allows you to specify the blend mode. Any background graphics must be in the blend group though. This is not a limitation if you just want transparency.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newfontfamily{\devanagari}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1, Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newcommand*{\tgopacity}{0.5}
\newcommand*{\tgblendmode}{normal}
\newcommand*{\tggraphics}{}
% \begin{transparentgroup}{opacity}{blend mode}{graphics within blend group}
\newenvironment{transparentgroup}[3]{%
  \renewcommand*{\tgopacity}{#1}%
  \renewcommand*{\tgblendmode}{#2}%
  \renewcommand{\tggraphics}{#3}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup
}{%
  \egroup
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
      inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, blend group=\tgblendmode
    ]
    \tggraphics
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=\tgopacity]
      \node [anchor=north west] {\box0};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green, opacity=0.5]
  ([yshift=7cm]current page.center) circle [radius=20pt];%
\begin{transparentgroup}{0.5}{lighten}{
    \fill[green, opacity=0.5] (10mm,-5mm) circle [radius=20pt];
  }
  \textcolor{red}{\devanagari एक गांव में पिताजी}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{transparentgroup}

\textcolor{red}{\devanagari एक गांव में पिताजी}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I have corrected the code in my original question, was applying transparency at a different level. According to tikz pgf manual, option `blend group` starts an implicit transparency group, so I didn't explicitly specify a tikz scope. Thanks for your very insightful explanation and crafty code, I have updated my question and referenced your answer. As you would read in `Update-2` of my question, all this question needs now is finding the transparency grouping code in tikz codebase & applying it outside. I would still prefer that as tikz has its own idiosyncrasies -- including slowness.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you want, but it's quite a pain. The example below has a simple interface to set material in a `\vbox` and allows you to set the opacity and blend mode.

The usage is:

```
\begin{transparencygroup}[
    opacity = < Value between 0 and 1 >,
    blend mode = < One of the standard PDF blend modes >
  ]
\end{transparencygroup}
```

Because of the poor interface for page resources, there can be problems with
other packages that add things to the page resources.

This sample code makes no attempt to work with other packages, so it **may not work properly** if you have other packages loaded that mess with `/ExtGState` (e.g., `tikz`, `colorspace`, `transparent`, `fontspec`'s Opacity feature, etc.). `tikz` provides a hook that could be used if you need to use `tikz`.

```
%! TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

% grouped transparency implementation

% Limitations:
%
% 1. Because of the poor interface for page resources, there can be problems
%    with other packages that add things to the /ExtGState dictionary (e.g.,
%    tikz, colorspace, transparent, etc.).
%
% 2. You can't use the Opacity feature of fontspec as this puts the
%    transparency code inside the transparency group, and you'll still get the
%    overlapping glyphs.
%
% 3. Only LuaLaTeX is supported.

\usepackage{l3pdf}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{everyshi}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\pdf_uncompress:


% l3pdf extensions (lualatex only)

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pdf_object_new:nn { xn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pdf_object_write:nn { xx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pdf_object_ref:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_xform_now:Nnn
  {
    \tex_immediate:D \tex_pdfxform:D
      attr { #2 }
      resources { #3 }
      #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_xform_now:Nnn { Nxx }

\cs_new_protected:Nx \__reportaman_pdf_xform_last:
  {
    \exp_not:N \int_value:w
    \exp_not:N \tex_pdflastxform:D
    \c_space_tl 0 ~ R
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_refxform_last:
  {
    \tex_pdfrefxform:D \tex_pdflastxform:D
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_pageresources_gput_right:nn
  {
    \tex_global:D
    \tex_pdfvariable:D pageresources
    \exp_after:wN
      {
        \tex_the:D \tex_pdfvariable:D pageresources / #1 ~ #2
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_pageresources_gput_right:nn { nx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_literal_direct:n
  {
    \tex_pdfextension:D literal direct
      {
        #1
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_literal_direct:n { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_save_gs:
  {
    \__reportaman_pdf_literal_direct:n { q }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_pdf_restore_gs:
  {
    \__reportaman_pdf_literal_direct:n { Q }
  }


% grouped transparency back end

\clist_new:N \g__reportaman_ca_clist
\clist_new:N \g__reportaman_bm_clist
\int_new:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reportaman_set_pdf_page_resources:
  {
    \clist_remove_duplicates:N \g__reportaman_ca_clist
    \clist_remove_duplicates:N \g__reportaman_bm_clist
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \g__reportaman_ca_clist
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
          {
            /reportaman_CA_##1 ~ << ~ /CA ~ ##1 ~ >> ~
            /reportaman_ca_##1 ~ << ~ /ca ~ ##1 ~ >> ~
          }
      }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \g__reportaman_bm_clist
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
          {
            /reportaman_bm_##1 ~ << ~ /BM ~ [ ~ /##1 ~ ] ~ >> ~
          }
      }
    \clist_gclear:N \g__reportaman_ca_clist
    \clist_gclear:N \g__reportaman_bm_clist
    \exp_args:Nx \pdf_object_if_exist:nT
      {
        reportaman_extgstate_ \int_use:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int
      }
      {
        \pdf_object_write:xx
          { reportaman_extgstate_ \int_use:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int }
          { \l_tmpa_tl }
        \__reportaman_pdf_pageresources_gput_right:nx
          { ExtGState }
          { 
            \pdf_object_ref:e
              {
                reportaman_extgstate_ \int_use:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int
              }
          }
        \int_gincr:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int
      }
  }

\EveryShipout { \__reportaman_set_pdf_page_resources: }

\keys_define:nn { reportaman }
{
  opacity      .tl_set:N           = \l__reportaman_opacity_tl,
  opacity      .value_required:n   = true,
  blend ~ mode .choice:,
  blend ~ mode .choices:nn         =
    { Normal, Multiply, Screen, Overlay, Darken, Lighten, ColorDodge,
      ColorBurn, HardLight, SoftLight, Difference, Exclusion, Hue, Saturation,
      Color, Luminosity }
    { \tl_set_eq:NN \l__reportaman_blend_mode_tl \l_keys_choice_tl },
  blend ~ mode .value_required:n   = true,
}


% grouped transparency front end
% \begin{transparencygroup}[
%   opacity = < Value between 0 and 1 >,
%   blend mode = < One of the standard PDF blend modes >
% ]
% \end{transparencygroup}
\NewDocumentEnvironment { transparentgroup }
  { o +b }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { reportaman }
      {
        opacity = { 1 },
        blend ~ mode = { Normal }
      }
    \IfValueT { #1 }
      {
        \keys_set:nn { reportaman } { #1 }
      }
    \clist_gput_right:Nx \g__reportaman_ca_clist { \l__reportaman_opacity_tl }
    \clist_gput_right:Nx \g__reportaman_bm_clist { \l__reportaman_blend_mode_tl }
    \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
      {
        \__reportaman_pdf_literal_direct:x
          {
            /reportaman_bm_\l__reportaman_blend_mode_tl \c_space_tl gs
          }
        #2
      }
    \exp_args:Nx \pdf_object_if_exist:nF
      {
        reportaman_extgstate_ \int_use:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int
      }
      {
        \pdf_object_new:xn
          { reportaman_extgstate_ \int_use:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int }
          { dict }
      }
    \__reportaman_pdf_xform_now:Nxx
      \l_tmpa_box
      { /Group ~ << ~ /S ~ /Transparency ~ /I ~ true ~ /K ~ false ~ >> }
      { /ExtGState ~
        \pdf_object_ref:e
        {
          reportaman_extgstate_ \int_use:N \g__reportaman_extgstate_int
        }
      }
    \__reportaman_pdf_save_gs:
    \__reportaman_pdf_literal_direct:x
      {
        /reportaman_CA_\l__reportaman_opacity_tl \c_space_tl gs \iow_newline:
        /reportaman_ca_\l__reportaman_opacity_tl \c_space_tl gs
      }
    \__reportaman_pdf_refxform_last:
    \__reportaman_pdf_restore_gs:
  }
  {
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


% Usage example

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\devanagari}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1, Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\begin{document}
\begin{transparentgroup}[opacity=0.25, blend mode=Hue]
  \devanagari\Huge
  \color{red}एक गांव में पिताजी

  \vspace{-7mm}\quad
  \color{green}एक गांव में पिताजी
\end{transparentgroup}

\begin{transparentgroup}[opacity=0.5]
  \devanagari\Huge
  \color{red}एक गांव में पिताजी

  \vspace{-7mm}\quad
  \color{blue}एक गांव में पिताजी
\end{transparentgroup}

\begin{transparentgroup}
  \devanagari\Huge
  \color{red}एक गांव में पिताजी

  \vspace{-7mm}\quad
  \color{yellow}एक गांव में पिताजी
\end{transparentgroup}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Seems to be getting somewhere closer. First observation: It interferes with latex code outside of your transparency group environment. For instance, `fontspec` `Opacity` doesn't work for other fonts outside of your environment `transparencygroup`. For your, "Because of the poor interface for page resources, there can be problems with other packages that add things to the page resources.", I wonder how tikz transparency group handles that; for instance I don't see it interacting with fontspec's `Opacity` both inside and outside tikz figures. "...that mess with /ExtGState", any example issue?

Comment: One more observation: In the screenshot you have posted here, the contents within the first transparency group seem to composite with each other (one can see red glyphs  through green glyphs) instead of being part of a group. What pdf reader did you click that from? Thanks

Comment: The reason `fontspec`'s opacity doesn't work is because both `fontspec` (via `luaotfload-colors.lua`) and the above code writes an `/ExtGState` dictionary to the page resources. The reason it works with `tikz` is because `luaotfload-colors.lua` tests if `tikz` is loaded and uses the `tikz` hook to add it's own things to `tikz`'s `/ExtGState` dictionary. There isn't really anything you can do about this (without loading `tikz`) until there's a consistent LaTeX3 interface for writing to the PDF page resources that *everyone* uses.

Comment: @reportaman, my point about the `/ExtGState` thing is that you could make it work with `fontspec`'s opactiy, but only by loading `tikz` (which you explicitly do not want to do). Then you could change my code to use `tikz`'s hook and `fontspec` would use `tikz`'s hook and it would work. There is no other way to get around this problem. You will run into the same issue with the `transparent` and `colorspace` packages. `tikz` is the only package that provides a hook for others to use, so all packages writing to `/ExtGState` use `tikz`. It's a limitation at the TeX engine level.

Comment: @reportaman, in theory the overlap you see in the first transparency group is because of the blend mode (Hue). The screenshot was produced with GhostScript. Chrome, Firefox, mupdf and Poppler also show it this way. Notably, Adobe Reader does not. This means that there is something missing in the code somewhere. I can make it work with `tikz`, but can't yet figure out where the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for these insights, that makes it very clear what is going on. Oh I didn't mean that I am not ok loading tikz, I just didn't want every page of document to have tikz pictures for what is actually just text. So if it simplifies, improves, and makes your above code more compatible with other packages, please update it to use tikz hooks (to `/ExtGState`) (perhaps an if condition if you wish, but not necessary). If that works without issues, like interfering with code outside your new environment, then we have a working solution for these scripts for the first time.

Comment: @reportaman, if you are going to load `tikz`, then you should use the `tikz` method. It will be more reliable and work with all TeX engines. The above code simply shows that you *can* do it without `tikz`, but in the end this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113896/discussion-between-reportaman-and-david-purton).