# transparent.sty overlapping text renders as gray in Acrobat

Tags: acrobat, transparent

I find that Adobe Acrobat (on Windows 11 and on Android) does not correctly render transparency produced via `transparent.sty` and PDFLaTeX.  Specifically, overlapping text comes out as a uniform gray.

Here's an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
\vbox{%
  \hbox{\texttransparent{0.5}{hello}}%
  \vskip-\baselineskip
  \hbox{\texttransparent{0.5}{world}}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Acrobat screenshot:

[image: Acrobat screenshot]

Chrome screenshot (similar in most other PDF viewers I've tried):

[image: Chrome screenshot]

I want to achieve the latter behavior, where overlapping text appears darker. Maybe Acrobat is using the wrong blend mode for transparency? (It does seem to blend properly with a background `\pagecolor`.) Is there a way to fix this? Perhaps one of the other ways to specify transparency in LaTeX would do better?

Comment: I just found a relevant past post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565281/luatex-pdftex-incorrect-transparency-for-fonts-with-overlapping-glyphs-achie
I'm going to see if I can get `\begin{transparencygroup}` working for my purposes... Oops, that's LuaTeX only I guess. I'd like to avoid the overhead of TikZ if possible.

Comment: General comment, slightly off-topic, but worth knowing: The issue raised in this question is one reason why most "print on demand" (to paper) services disallow vector artwork, transparency, and overlaps. Not specific to TeX. Rather, different software (such as the printer's firmware) may render differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Acrobat treats text in the same text object as if it were in a knockout transparency group, leading to the observed behavior. This is a configurable graphic state parameter (`TK` for "**t**ext **k**nockout") which you can turn off:

```tex
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex, transparent}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn { Page / Resources / ExtGState } { no.text.knockout } { << /TK~false >> }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ifpdftex
  \newcommand \disabletextknockout {%
    \pdfliteral page {/no.text.knockout gs}%
  }
\else
  \RequireLuaTeX
  \newcommand \disabletextknockout {%
    \pdfextension literal page {/no.text.knockout gs}%
  }
\fi
\begin{document}
\disabletextknockout
\vbox{%
  \hbox{\texttransparent{0.5}{hello}}%
  \vskip-\baselineskip
  \hbox{\texttransparent{0.5}{world}}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that sounds amazing! I couldn't actually get your example to run; my pdflatex(TeX Live 2023/Cygwin) complains that `\pdfextension` isn't defined. Is `\pdfextension` supposed to be available in pdflatex or just luatex? Also, for us LaTeX2e luddites, is there an analog to `\pdfmanagement_add:nnn` or do I need to evolve to expl3?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you still use pdfLaTeX. Just replace `\pdfextension literal` with `\pdfliteral`. I don't think there's another name for `pdfmanagement_add:nnn`, but you can reduce the `ExplSyntax` block by defining an alias usable outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, it works great now! Finally time to learn expl3 I guess. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use tikz. It puts the text inside an XObjects, and adobe handles that slightly differently to text which is directly in the stream. (It is probably possible to get a similar effect with transparent at the page group level, but the description in the pdf reference is rather long and I don't have the time to figure out which setting is needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz {
\node[black,opacity=0.5] {hello};
\node[black,opacity=0.5] {world};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my setting, I wanted to use the same box logic but only have a different implementation of `\texttransparent` (to replace `transparent.sty`).  I found the following PGF-based solution, based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565470/245104, to work well:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\textopacity[2]{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{#1}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \pgftext[base]{#2}%
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\vbox{%
  \hbox{\textopacity{0.5}{hello}}%
  \vskip-\baselineskip
  \hbox{\textopacity{0.5}{world}}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Acrobat screenshot:

[image: Acrobat screenshot]

I'd still prefer a solution that doesn't rely on PGF. I tried figuring out how PGF maps to PDF XObjects via `\pdfxform` but my attempts failed.