# How to get this font in the picture ("MAX-MIN ant system" italic curved font)

Tags: fonts, italic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)

can you help me find the right command for this font in the picture, look at the "MAX-MIN" words. Thank you

[image: max-min ant system]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loos like using `\mathcal`? Three options: with a minus sign treated as an ordinary atom, with a minus sign and negative spaces and with a hyphen between the words:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{MAX}{-}\mathcal{MIN}$

$\mathcal{MAX}\text{-}\mathcal{MIN}$

$\mathcal{MAX}\!{-}\!\mathcal{MIN}$

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `\text{-}`?

Comment: @egreg: might be. The hyphen looks too small? I've added your suggestion and another additional option.

Comment: and I think it's the one with $\mathcal{MAX}\!{-}\!\mathcal{MIN}$