# How can I change the math font in slides class?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, presentations

I use the "slides" class to get full size equations for a presentation. (Yes, it needs to be in Powerpoint ;) )

However, I want to have the standard math font (like in the `article` class). There seems to be no option like `serif` for the `beamer` class. The reason, I'm not using the `beamer` class is that I get a "picture" just the size of my equation in Powerpoint with the `slides` class. With `beamer` or `article`, I get a bigger "picture" with a lot of white space around my equation.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{slides}\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}  
\begin{equation*}  
\Omega 
\end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that you want to use the `standalone` class instead of `slides`.

Comment: That does work, indeed. Could it be, that the slides class just has a default \begin{huge} ... \end{huge} in it? Seems like the symbols are about that size. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Try pdfscreen.  I like to use a 4.5" by 6" for 3x4 screens, or 4.5" by 8" for 9x16 wide screen.

Comment: To get equation numbers with standalone, use parbox to set the width.

Answer (score 2):

I just followed egreg's lead in his answer at [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode/58103#58103), which indicated how the LaTeX kernel sets up math fonts.

```
\documentclass{slides}\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}    {operators}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}   {symbols}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbf}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathit}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathtt}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}  
\begin{equation*}  
y = mx + b ~~~\omega\Omega \mathbf{\Omega}\mathit{\Omega} 
\end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note: equation also has margins, so you really can't get much smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}


\margins{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\screensize{1in}{4in}
\backgroundcolor{lightgray}% to show margins

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A = \pi r^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]