# script F (or something like it)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

How can I enter this 'F' in LaTeX?

`\mathcal{F}` looks quite similar to it, but a little bit different.

I prefer not to use additional package if possible.

Comment: In the above linked page, the closest seems to be `Boondox`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
$\mathscr{F}$
```

Take a look at [*What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/341)