# How to type this symbol in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

Just want to know how to type this symbol in Latex. I saw it used in the axioms of probability. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `\mathfrak{F}` should do.

Comment: Seems to be ``Euler fraktur bold`` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode).