# Digits from an other font

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

In a book that I'm currentlry rewriting they use special digits for numbers.
Although I searched for this shape in Tex Font Catalogue I didn't find exactly 
matching shape of digits. The only thing similar was antiqua fraktur for 2.
Do you know a latex font which has these shapes of digits?
[image: strange digits]

Can I use only digits from other font in the whole document?

Comment: Your term "antiqua fraktur" is a bit ambiguous: "Antiqua" is generally used as a synonym for "Roman", which is rather different from "Fraktur".

Comment: Yes in deed, my mistake. I was misled by some picture in the internet showing Goethe Fraktur.

Comment: can you add a scan of some text which uses two different fonts for the digits?  or is it just that the shape of *all* digits is different from the shapes available with most fonts used with tex?

Comment: All, but I want to preserve the original design. The book is available as scanned pdf: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/mon/mon19/mon1901.pdf

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple packages with such 'oldstyle' digits/number, I used all possible (some did not work) fonts for the `bookhands` collection of fonts, basically medieval fonts and three fonts (Gothic,Fraktur, Schwabacher) from `yfonts` package, for example the `Early Gothic`, the `Gothic Textura Precious`, the `Rotunda` and the `Humanist` and defined a command just to print out a number with the Early Gothic (`\egothfamily` command) as default optional argument value.

The loop is used to print multiple values at once vertically, it is just for output and example, not for production.

Please look at the documentation of `yfonts`  and further font examples 
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/bookhands

In general, this requires a `fontname` package, e.g. `egothic` which should also provide the required font files and a font switching command, often called something like `\...family`.

The family names are listed here:

```
\forcsvlist{\listadd{\MyFontFamilyList}}{sqrcfamily,rustfamily,unclfamily,hunclfamily,imajfamily,iminfamily,cminfamily,gothfamily,swabfamily,frakfamily,egothfamily,pgothfamily,rtndfamily,hminfamily}
```

Just prepend a `\` to the corresponding name -- this will activate the corresponding font. Switching like this results that all following text will be typeset in this font until another switch appears.

In order to prevent, that typesetting a single digit or short number with such a font will result in consequent text to be in the same font, I made the font change in the `\OldStyleNumber` command within a `\begingroup...\endgroup`, so it is only active inside that group.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{sqrcaps}%
\usepackage{rustic}%
\usepackage{uncial}%
\usepackage{auncial}%
\usepackage{huncial}%
\usepackage{inslrmaj}%
\usepackage{inslrmin}%
\usepackage{carolmin}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{egothic}%
\usepackage{pgothic}%
\usepackage{rotunda}%
\usepackage{humanist}%
\usepackage{yfonts}%




\newcommand{\OldStyleNumber}[2][\egothfamily]{%
\begingroup%
#1 #2%
\endgroup%
}%

\newcounter{innercounter}

\newcounter{outercounter}

\gdef\MyFontFamilyList{}%
\listadd{\MyFontFamilyList}{}%



\newcounter{maxfamilies}
\setcounter{innercounter}{0}




\newcommand{\showfonttableheaderlist}[1]{%
\ifnumless{\number\value{innercounter}}{\number\value{maxfamilies}}{%
\rotatebox{90}{\(\backslash\)#1}  &%
}{%
\rotatebox{90}{\(\backslash\)#1}% 
}%
\stepcounter{innercounter}%
}%

\newcommand{\showoldstylenumberlist}[1]{%
\ifnumless{\number\value{innercounter}}{\number\value{maxfamilies}}{%
\OldStyleNumber[\csname #1\endcsname]{\number\value{outercounter}} &%
}{%
\OldStyleNumber[\csname #1\endcsname]{\number\value{outercounter}}%
}%
\stepcounter{innercounter}%
}%


\newcommand{\showoldstylenumberlinelist}[1]{%
\(\backslash\)#1 & \OldStyleNumber[\csname #1\endcsname]{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} \tabularnewline
}%



\begin{document}

\setcounter{maxfamilies}{15}

\forcsvlist{\listadd{\MyFontFamilyList}}{sqrcfamily,rustfamily,unclfamily,hunclfamily,imajfamily,iminfamily,cminfamily,gothfamily,swabfamily,frakfamily,egothfamily,pgothfamily,rtndfamily,hminfamily}

\begin{center}
\Large \textbf{Overview medieval fonts and number style}%

\end{center}



\large \bfseries

\begin{tabular}{*{16}{c}}%
%\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccc}
\rotatebox{90}{Normal} & \forlistloop{\showfonttableheaderlist}{\MyFontFamilyList} \tabularnewline
\forloop{outercounter}{0}{\number\value{outercounter} < 10}{%
\setcounter{innercounter}{0}%
\number\value{outercounter} &
\forlistloop{\showoldstylenumberlist}{\MyFontFamilyList} \tabularnewline 
} %
\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}%

\normalsize
\setcounter{innercounter}{0}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\forlistloop{\showoldstylenumberlinelist}{\MyFontFamilyList} \tabularnewline 
\end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

In my point of view `Rotunda` or `Humanist` resemble most what you need, but there might be other fonts as well.

[image]

Comment: As I found in this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode yfonts package provides quite similar \textfrak{}

Comment: @user15941: Shall I add it to my answer or do you want want to answer yourself?

Comment: You add it to your answer for people who will be serching for that in future.

Comment: @user15941: I have updated the answer and added some more fonts