# How to use Boondox calligraphic font in LaTeX without replacing \mathcal command

Tags: fonts, errors, formatting, packages, font-encodings

This is a follow-up question to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201050/how-to-use-boondox-latex-calligraphic-font) I asked about how to use the `Boondox` calligraphic font alongside the standard `\mathcal` font. The [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201056/48036) involved getting the `\mathalfa` package running, which replaced the original font (produced by the `\mathcal` command) with the Boondox font. The second step was to create a separate command (e.g. `\mathcalorig`), which would be used to call upon the original, "standard" calligraphic font again.

My question now: Is it possible to achieve both fonts working alongside each other without outright replacing `\mathcal`? For instance, I would like for `\mathcal` to output the original "standard" calligraphic font, and give the boondox font (which I don't use nearly as often) its own command, e.g. `\mathcalboondox`. Then in summary we would have:

- Typing `\mathcal` produces the regular behavior you expect, i.e. gives you the standard calligraphic style we're familiar with
- Typing `\mathcalboondox` will give you the boondox-style font on the rare occasion you want to use that instead of regular `\mathcal`

Here's a picture describing what I'm looking for:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: May be a `\let\oldmathcal\mathcal` before `\usepackage[..]{mathalfa}` and then define whatever you want with `\oldmathcal` or `\mathcal`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's simpler to do by hand what `mathalfa` does:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{\skewchar\font=45 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{m}{n}{
  <-> s*[1.05] BOONDOX-r-calo}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{b}{n}{
  <-> s*[1.05] BOONDOX-b-calo}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalboondox}{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcalboondox}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbcalboondox}{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABC}$ $\mathcalboondox{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there's a different way, with `mathalfa`, which allows to call the alphabet as `\mathscr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABC}$ $\mathscr{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks simple and works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: mathalfa (https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) allows you to choose from a bunch of fonts for cal, frak, bb, etc. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new math alphabet and load a `BOONDOX-scr` package with `\mathscr` and `\\mathbscr` commands in the place of `\mathcal` and `mathbcal`, transpose from the original `BOONDOX-cal` package. Here is the small code for the new package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{boondox-scr}[2015/05/29 v1 U/BOONDOX-scr]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%
\define@key{BOONDOX-scr.sty}{scaled}[1.0]{%
\expandafter\def\csname BOONDOX-scr@scale\endcsname {#1}}%
\ExecuteOptionsX<BOONDOX-scr.sty>{scaled}%
\ProcessOptionsX<BOONDOX-scr.sty>\relax%
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbscr} {U}{BOONDOX-cal}{b}{n}
\endinput


        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{boondox-scr}
        \pagestyle{empty}

        \begin{document}%
        \textbf{%
        Boondox :
        }%

        \[ \begin{array}[t]{c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c}
            \verb+ \mathcal + & \verb+ \mathscr + & \verb+ \mathbscr +\\[6pt]
            \mathcal{EMTS} & \mathscr{LnS} & \mathbscr{LnS}
            \end{array} \]%

        \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]Code incorporated in the preamble:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
         \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{m}{n}
         \SetMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{b}{n}
         \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbscr} {U}{BOONDOX-cal}{b}{n}
        \pagestyle{empty}

        \begin{document}%
        \textbf{%
        Boondox :
        }%

        \[ \begin{array}[t]{c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c}
            \verb+ \mathcal + & \verb+ \mathscr + & \verb+ \mathbscr +\\[6pt]
            \mathcal{EMTS} & \mathscr{LnS} & \mathbscr{LnS}
            \end{array} \]%

        \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks for your answer. Where does the top code go, in the preamble? I'm getting a lot of errors, starting with  "Undefined control sequence \define".

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: Sorry, I  posted an old version of the files. I've updated the post. So,, the topcode can be **either** saved as a `boondox-scr` file, in your local  TeXMF  root (whatever the name of the local root, more precisely in `\localroottex\latex\boondox`), then refresh the FNDB if you're under MiKTeX, or the equivalent under TeX Live, **or** leave it in the same direcrory as your main file, **or** incorporate the code in your preamble, between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: Hi Bernard, I'm trying to include the top code in the preamble (between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` as you said). I'm getting the error `File 'boondox-scr.sty' not found. \pagestyle`. Here's a link to your sample code I've entered in an online LaTeX editor/compiler: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5569db658576bc3369cdace0

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: I think you misunderstood what has to be done: I posted an example of a `boondox-src.sty`,  to be put in the same directory as the main file or in a places searched by latex, **or** to be incorporated in the main file preamble. I upd