# Like \ell but for j

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm in a slightly annoying situation where I've used the letter j as an index, but now also want to use a lower case j for something else. Ideally I wouldn't want to do that, but changing either would require changing loads of other notation throughout the document. So I want to find a letter that's (a) clearly a lower case j, but (b) looks different from the usual math mode j.

I tried using `\mathcal{j}`, provided by the `dutchcal` package. With the (mandatory) style file I'm using it looks like this:

[image]

The two j's do look different, but it's a bit subtle and doesn't really give the impression that they're different characters with different meanings.

I also tried just using a unicode , but that rendered as "??" with the style file I'm using.

I'm hoping to find a lower case j more in the style of `\ell`, with its very deliberate loop that makes it look quite distinct from a normal italic l:

[image]

Does such a glyph exist in any standard package that can be used with `pdflatex`?

Edit: I actually found a more satisfactory answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373518/12461) using the Stix fonts, so I'm not sure if I should delete this question now. With that answer I get this:

[image]

It looks stylistically a bit weird due to the slope being even greater than the italic j. (Honestly, I don't like the way it looks in my document at all.) But at least it's very clear that the two j's are different.

Comment: I like the diamond shape of the dot produced by `\mathcal{j}`. :-) I would agree with you, though, that many (most?) readers won't notice the visual differences between math-mode `j` and `\mathcal{j}`.

Comment: As a note for future reference, you can always answer your own question. Part of the purpose of the Stack Exchange sites is to provide a q&a reference for future searchers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `boondoxo` calligraphics seem to fit the bill.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalpha}

\newcommand\jay{\mathcal{j}}

\begin{document}
\[ \jay ( i \to j ) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Boondoxo font sample]

You edited your answer to mention that you had found the STIX fonts.  This has a similar style, but I personally prefer this less-slanted version.

You could also load this alphabet as `\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalpha}` and use it as `\mathscr{j}`, leaving `\mathcal` untouched.

While you ask about PDFTeX-compatible packages, anyone using `unicode-math` can get a very similar `\mathscr` alphabet with the command

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={scr,bfscr},
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  StylisticSet=1 ]
```

If you need to use three different mathematical script alphabets in the same paper, yet you must use a legacy engine that limits you to sixteen 8-bit math alphabets, you might adapt the relevant commands from `BOONDOX-uprscr.sty` and `uboondoxuprscr.fd` and reconsider some of your choices in life.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{boondoxuprscr}{\skewchar \font =45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{boondoxuprscr}{m}{n}{
    <-> BOONDOXUprScr-Regular}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{boondoxuprscr}{b}{n}{
    <-> BOONDOXUprScr-Bold}{}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathboondoxo}{U}{boondoxuprscr}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathboondoxo}{bold}{U}{boondoxuprscr}{b}{n}

\newcommand\jay{\mathboondoxo{j}}

\begin{document}
\[ \jay ( i \to j ) \]
\end{document}
```

You can also get this one symbol without using up one of your limited math alphabets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{boondoxuprscr}{\skewchar \font =45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{boondoxuprscr}{m}{n}{
    <-> BOONDOXUprScr-Regular}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{boondoxuprscr}{b}{n}{
    <-> BOONDOXUprScr-Bold}{}

\newcommand\jay{\text{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{boondoxuprscr}\fontshape{n}\selectfont j}}

\begin{document}
\[ \jay ( i \to j ) \]
\end{document}
```

This implementation does not support `\boldsymbol{\jay}`, but will use the bold version if the surrounding text is bold.  It assumes you will be setting `\bfseries\boldmath` at the same time.  To always use the medium weight, add `\fontseries{m}` before `\selectfont`.

Comment: Great, this looks loads better than the Stix one

Comment: @Davislor: Is it possible to get this 'j' character without kiboshing any character besides lowercase 'j' in either the `\mathcal` or `\mathscr` fonts?

Comment: @COTO Yes, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247531/how-to-use-boondox-calligraphic-font-in-latex-without-replacing-mathcal-command).

Answer (score 7):

You can [try](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=tex.stackexchange&question=28340&printer=false&linktohome=true) also [MathTime Professional 2 Fonts](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) where the "complete" version provides a complete math typesetting environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[mtpccal]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{j}(i\to j)$ and $\mathcal{l}(i\to j)$ (comparated with $\ell(i\to j)$)
\end{document}
```

[image]