# Incomplete \ifcase when using mathalfa

Tags: fonts, mathalfa

I learnt some time ago that I could use `mathalfa` to replace the "blackboard" style of letters in my tex documents. I much prefer the "sans-serif" look styles like `boondox` provide over the default look, so much I have the following line in pretty much all my files' preambles:

`\usepackage[bb=boondox,scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}`

However, after a while of not using tex and after some miktex updates, this gives me errors, so I created this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bb=boondox,scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
    This is a simple test.
    \[ f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \]
\end{document}
```

Removing the line `\usepackage[bb=stix2,scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}` will render the file properly, but I don't know how to get the "sans-serif" look to that font now.

The error I get is:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbb' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/BOONDOX-ds/m/n --> U/BOONDOX-ds/b/n on input line 205
.
)
! Incomplete \ifcase; all text was ignored after line 700.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

Which is funny since this is a 12 line file. Any ideas on how can I achieve that now? Here's what I've tried:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201062/89382

I also tried setting `\newcommand\bmmax{0}` and `\newcommand\hmmax{0}` to different values, since I had recollection those could interfere in something.

Also, it might be relevant to note I often use Linux, and this file rendered last week on linux without issue (I assume that means TexLive isn't affected?), but bringing it to Windows (where I use Miktex) started giving me the issue.

Another point is that I used that code on multiple older files, and both Miktex and Texlive worked for it, so perhaps a recent update?

Comment: the mathalpha.sty version in miktex is a bit older than the current in texlive, and a comparision shows a missing \fi. You will have to wait until miktex catches up with the update (it is often a few days behind texlive).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - indeed, after updating it last night the issue was resolved. I suppose you should write this as an answer so I can accept it and mark the issue as solved?