# How to tex this symbol?

Tags: math-mode

I am wondering how to type those kinds of symbols in LATEX. Please help me.

[image: some professors use it to represent closed sets]

[image: some professors use it to represent open sets]

Thank you very much!

Comment: `\mathfrak{F}`.

Comment: Have you seen [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/21930

Answer (score 2):

`$\mathfrak{F}($` and `$\mathfrak{G}$`