# How do you write Munkre's topology T?

Tags: fonts

In James Munkres' classic topology textbook, he writes a topology T using a typeface I am unfamiliar with.

I tried looking it up using detexify and checking commonly used character sets but the closest I could find was a capital fraktur I.

[image: echanScriptT]

Comment: Hi, could you please post an image of  how the letter looks like?

Comment: Instead of linking, you could make a screenshot, clip the image to show just a few symbols and post it here. The pdf file you linked to is quite large.

Comment: That looks like `\mathcal` or some script T.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have updated my post. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I would simply dupe that to [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098) You can pick one from the very very good answer. Most likely, you want `eulervm`.

Comment: Echan, Still, the pic was linked to another page instead of posted here on our server.

Comment: @Johannes_B That link is precisely what I was looking for, I wish I've seen that years ago. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Echan So which one of the ones at the linked answer is the one Munkres uses?