# Latex in relational algebra

Tags: pdftex

I am new to Latex. 
I am trying to prepare a document in relational algebra using latex.

For this code in Latex :

```
\textbf{Optimization on R1:}
{\large
By applying $ \sigma_{\varphi}(R_{1} \bowtie R_{2}) \equiv  R_{1} \bowtie \sigma_{\varphi}( R_{2} )   if  \varphi  contains  only   attributes in R_{2}, we have : $ 
}
```

I am getting the output as

[image]

I don't know why I am getting the last line without space. Please help me with it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX code between the character $ is used to write math expressions: in your example, all the line is described in this way.

```
\textbf{Optimization on R1:} {\large By applying $ \sigma_{\varphi}(R_{1} \bowtie R_{2}) \equiv R_{1} \bowtie \sigma_{\varphi}( R_{2} )$ if $\varphi $ contains only attributes in $ R_{2} $, we have : }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, all letters in math-mode (anything between $...$) are interpreted as mathematical expressions (variables, ...). If you want to write text within math-mode, use `\mathrm{some text}` for normal roman-type text, `\mathit{italic text}` / `\mathbf{bold text}` for italic / bold text.

If you still have to enforce blank spaces, you can use `~` (e.g., `\mathrm{~if~}`)

Also see, [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)