# command for calligraphic lowercase latin and greek letters

Tags: math-mode, fonts, characters, calligraphy

I am wondering whether `calligraphic type` command exists, that supports both Greek and Latin (lowercase) characters in math-environment. Let's say that I have:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\phi=3x+5$
\end{document}
```

So, how can I present `\phi` with a calligraphic font?

Comment: Hello, There might be no calligraphic \phi symbol in latex. However, there is a font catalogue which might be of additional interest.  (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/)  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)

Comment: Thanks, but this is does not help me, since I do not only want `\phi` to be calligraphy, but also to be in `math-mode`.

Comment: this no real answer but there (one of the ams-packages, amssymb would make sense) is `\varphi` which looks a bit nicer

Comment: the problem with `\var` command is that i cannot apply it for latin characters.  i also wonder whether that command can be used for other greek characters.