# Invariant Amplitude (fractal) M (font or code)

Tags: fonts

Good day Tex-Community,

I need to use this this specific fractal M character in my presentation. I've taken a photograph down below. What command/package do I have to use?
[image]

Comment: This is some sort of calligraphic/script uppercase M, not “fractal” (you probably meant Fraktur).

Comment: It is taken from the book Quarks & Leptons by Halzen and Martin.

Comment: Just use a calligraphic M. The actual shape carries no meaning.

Comment: It is a very old book (1984) typeset by something other than TeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `eufrak` or the `yfonts` package. For an extensive overview see ["What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124/110998)

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\begin{document}
From the \texttt{yfonts} package: 
$\textfrak{M}$,
$\textswab{M}$,
$\textgoth{M}$

From the \texttt{eufrak} package: 
$\mathfrak{M}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Those Ms look different from my photo though. I'm familiar with the link you provided, but none of the Ms I found there matches with the one in the picture. :/

Answer (score 4):

Using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) I found this as the closest match to your symbol

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathfrak{M}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use `$$` in LaTeX

Comment: @egreg as a less than experienced user, thanks for setting me straight and for asking nicely :) I'll not make that mistake again.

Comment: There's no LaTeX police that chases you for using `$$`; but since its usage is deprecated in LaTeX (see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)) and these pages are read by beginners, we're quite strict in removing the wrong usages. I'm glad you didn't take it personally. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

If suggest to use either `$\mathcal{M}$` or

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


$\mathscr{M}$
```

For exactly the same shape you are quoting you will need some special font to be determined.