# How can one alter one letter for mathematical notation?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, font-encodings

LaTeX has a lot of different fonts and symbols that can be used in math mode (see [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)). However the capital G character in these fonts are either based on the traditional roman alphabet (they literally look like this G) or are a script variant resembling the following image:

[image]

While some may like this style, I am personally more a fan of the alternate script G (common to cursive and certain logos like General Mills):

[image]

This is a vector based drawing I made of that variant.
My question is how can I best include this single letter so that way in math mode I can call it?

Following @PietvanOostrum's answer I now have:

[image]

which, while not perfect, I like better than the alternative:
[image]

for describing a directed graph G with vertex set V and arc set A.

Or now a third variant based on kurrent:
[image]

V and A are made by the `\mathbf{}` command.

How come they are raised so high?

Comment: that's a G? :-) Do you want to include the drawing (in which case `\includegraphics`) or do you have a font with a glyph that shape (which I would never have guessed to be a G!) in which case we'd need to know the font name and character number to suggest any code.

Comment: It is a variant of the cursive G. Google Image search cursive G and it will be there :) I do not have a font with a glyph like that currently. I can download one, where there are many. I just didn't know what is the best approach - use a font, or an image?

Comment: image is easier just `\includeimage[height=1.2ex]{myg}` but depends a bit whether you want cut and paste or search from the pdf to "know" it's a G in which case a font would be easier, if you have one

Comment: I would guess few readers would be able to read such a symbol though.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to put it in a fonts, maybe as a replacement for the letter G in a copy of an existing font. You could do this for example with `fontforge`.

As second best I would recommend to put the image inside a `mathord` command. In that case it would be best to use a PDF version, as that would be scalable. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\varG{\mathord{\raisebox{-0.15em}{\includegraphics[width=1em]{varG}}}}
\begin{document}

\Huge
\[ \left( \mathcal{G} = \varG \right) \]

\end{document}
```

where `varG.pdf` would be the image file.

[image]

I would also recommend to make it a bit fatter.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know some people are not a fan of this alternate G, but something about the standard script G used to define a graph doesn't look right...

Comment: I added some edits above. How come the arguments in `\left(` and `\right)` are raised?

Comment: They are not raised. This is the normal height. Look for example at `Text G(V, A) and math $F(x, X)$`. You will see that the parentheses are such that they are centered around the small letter x. Which means that if you put a capital inside, the capital looks raised, but it is not. It's just that the parentheses are sticking a bit below the baseline.