# No lower-case caligraphic or double fonts in LyX

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I'm new to LaTeX and LyX in general, and my question might be an easy one.

I'm having problems in working with some of the mathematical fonts. The upper-case characters seem to work just fine, but when it comes to lower-case letters and numbers, I get either default-font letters/num1bers or random characters instead of the letters/numbers I try to print. For example:

[image: problem description]

I'm using the default settings in lyX, and haven't touched anything so far.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Compiling the above document yields the following errors:

- "Missing character: There is no b in font msbm10!"
- "Missing character: There is no a in font rsfs10!"
- Reiteration of the above errors where "b" and "a" are replaced by other characters.

Comment: The special fonts don't generally define all the characters that you'd find in a general purpose font, so when the error message says "There is no b in msbm10" that is exactly what it means: there is no "b" character defined in "msbm10" (which is another name for mathbb I think).  The reason is that the other spaces in the font are used for other formatting characters, as you have seen.

Comment: @Thruston Do you have any suggestion for me? Are there any other free usable fonts?

Comment: why do you want to write mathcal, mathbb and mathscr in lower case?   I think they are normally only used with upper case letters in maths.

Comment: See here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ for the general font catalogue

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode which has a better explanation of what I was trying to say.