# Don't know how to type loopy X character in latex

Tags: math-mode, mathcal

I have a textbook which uses the following character to represent a matrix:

[image]

I would like to use the same character in my assignment, but I can't figure out how to type it. I tried `\chi` and `\mathcal{X}`, but they produce different results.

Comment: Welcome! Where is the image from? If from a PDF, what fonts does it use? Something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLK7B.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the "X" from Euler script, as shown in the table below, just under the "Calligraphic" header, in the "Upright" subsection.

Table was taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode).

[image]

Comment: Yup, I added `\usepackage{eucal}` at the top of my file, and `\mathcal{X}` produces the correct output now. Could you elaborate on how you would use the scripts from the table that you posted? I'm not exactly sure what `\mathcal` does, and why `\usepackage{eucal}` changes its output? Thanks!

Comment: @ostrokach `\mathcal` is for calligraphic math symbols, and `\usepackage{euler}` changes the output because it sets a different typeface for math.