# Use LaTeX math symbol fonts in other programs

Tags: math-mode, fonts

In my LaTeX document, I have used `\mathbb` and `\mathscr`. I would like to use the same fonts in the diagrams I create with Microsoft Visio. But on my Windows machines I cannot find `mbboard` and `mathrsfs` fonts as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode).

Where can I find these fonts?

Answer (score 1):

The native fonts are not in a format suitable for use outside of TeX, but an OpenType clone called Latin Modern has a maths font available for download [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html).

After installing this font file in your operating system, in the usual way, you will find these letters in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols range. The 'blackboard bold' letters (`\mathbb`) are in the Unicode range U+1D538 through U+1D56B (with some letters in the Letterlike Symbols range U+2102 through U+2149), and the script letters (`\mathscr`) are in the Unicode range U+1D49C through U+1D4B5 (bold script letters are also available).

These are not available as a separate font; entering these symbols must be done using either the `Insert > Symbol` feature in Microsoft Visio, or through the Windows Character Map.