# How to use "Mathematica Fraktur"?

Tags: fonts

I'm having a lot of difficulty in finding an explicit explanation of how to use the "Mathematica Fraktur", as defined in the top answer of this post: [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode?answertab=active#tab-top)

I suppose then my question is:

How, when using `$\mathfrak{A}$`, do I get the output to be the letter `A`, but in the font "Mathematica Fraktur", without changing the font of my entire document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That font is commercial, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the font in question, then you can use the `mathalfa`package as mentioned in the answer linked in the question.

The explicit explanation you were asking for is this: The [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa) of the `mathalfa` package states, that the following command would select "Mathematica Fraktur" for the output of `\mathfrak` and `\mathbfrak`:

```
\usepackage[frak=mma]{mathalfa}
```

Comment: It would seem, though, that this solution still relies on you owning the font, however.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you must own the font. This is just an answer to the bit about setting a font for `\mathfrak` without changing the font for the whole document. I will adjust my answer accordingly.