# Looking for a special mathcal / mathscr font

Tags: mathcal

Achim Blumensath uses some very strange font in his books about logic and model theory (see e.g. here: http://www.fi.muni.cz/~blumens/MSO.pdf)

I would really like to use the same for my documents, but I cannot find this particular font he is using. I checked out every possible font from here [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode) and here http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html (at least those which did not crash while compiling). But especially the calligraphic P (see last line on page 6 of his MSO book) seems to be completely unavailable - I cannot find it anywhere else.

Comment: as you have the pdf, the pdffonts utility or the fonts menu in acrobat and some other viewers tells you exactly what fonts are in the file,  a mix of cmss, minion pro and mn symbols and DS-Wartburg-Fraktur in this case

Comment: the full list is MinionPro-Regular , MinionPro-Subh , MinionPro-ItDisp , MinionPro-It , MinionPro-SemiboldCapt , MnSymbol10 , MnSymbol7 , MinionPro-Regular , DS-Wartburg-Fraktur , MinionPro-ItSubh , MinionPro-Semibold , MinionPro-Capt , MnSymbol10 , MnSymbol10 , MSBM10 , MnSymbol10 , MinionPro-ItCapt , MnSymbol8 , EUFM10 , MinionPro-Regular , MinionPro-It , MinionPro-SemiboldItCapt , MnSymbol6 , MnSymbol5 , MnSymbol9 , MinionPro-It , CMSS8 , CMSS10 , MnSymbol7 , MnSymbol7 , MinionPro-Bold , CMSS9 , MnSymbol9

Comment: I see Fraktur (`\mathfrak`) and standard `\mathcal`; the fancy P is `\powerset` from `MnSymbol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is set in Minion Pro, possibly with `mathspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

\[
R^{\powerset(A)}:=\{\bar{P}\in\powerset(A)^n \mid \dots \bar{a}\in R^{\mathfrak{A}}\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Original image (the overbar is different):

[image]