# \varmathbb and package txfonts restricted to math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, computer-modern

This question is related to this one: [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I would like to know if it is possible to use the command `\varmathbb{}`, that according to the accepted answer needs either the package `txfonts` or the package `pxfonts` (I am using the former), without extending the usage of the font to the *entire* document (thus leaving computer modern as the standard font).

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Terrible typo (but now corrected)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the font defined by `newtxmath`, with some help (the characters are not in the standard font position).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% from newtxmath
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{<-> ntxmia }{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{<-> ntxbmia }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\varmathbb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varmathbb}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \use:c { varbb##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mathbb_define:Nn
 {
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{\mathord}{lettersA}{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mathbb_define:Nn {ce}
\tl_map_inline:nn { ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ }
 {
  \__mathbb_define:ce { varbb#1 } { \int_eval:n { `#1+67 } }
 }
\tl_map_inline:nn { abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz }
 {
  \__mathbb_define:ce { varbb#1 } { \int_eval:n { `#1+61 } }
 }
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varbbimath}{\mathord}{lettersA}{'270}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varbbjmath}{\mathord}{lettersA}{'271}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathbb{C}\mathbb{R}\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{k}\mathbb{l}\mathbb{m}$

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZklmn}$

$\varbbimath\varbbjmath$

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Old answer (kept for those who still run TeX Live 2018)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% from newtxmath
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{<-> ntxmia }{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{<-> ntxbmia }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\varmathbb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varmathbb}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \use:c { varbb##1 }
   }
 }
\tl_map_inline:nn { ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ }
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \DeclareMathSymbol{varbb#1}{\mathord}{lettersA}{\int_eval:n { `#1+64 }}
 }
\exp_args:Nc \DeclareMathSymbol{varbbk}{\mathord}{lettersA}{169}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathbb{C}\mathbb{R}\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{k}$

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZk}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot (as always). If there are no other options I will go for that, but – to me – it really looks very close to the standard `\mathbb`.

Comment: @Kolmin Sorry, I misinterpreted your requirement. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is (almost) what I was looking for. :-) That is, now everytime there is a `\mathbb`it switches automatically to that nice `\varmathbb`. However, can the two types of fonts coexist, with `\mathbb` as usual and also `\varmathbb` to get that nice effect?

Comment: @Kolmin Just remove the `\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\varmathbb}` instruction and use `\varmathbb{A}` for the modified letters.

Comment: Great, thanks! (Sorry, I could open the page only now).

Comment: The solution works great (+1), except (for some reasons beyond my understanding) I had to change `\int_eval:n { \`#1+64 }` into `\int_eval:n { \`#1+67 }` to make it work in my document. Otherwise, `\varmathbb{R}` would print letter "O" and similarly all other letters be shifted back by 3.

Comment: @egreg (I don't know if I should open a new question for this) Related to my previous comment, your code on _exactly the same_ document gives different results if compiled on two different laptops (in mine I need the `+67` fix, whereas in another one the original `+64` works). Any reason why this is the case?

Comment: @AndreasT The fonts changed and moved the letters three positions forward.