# How to change font/design of equations?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, mathdesign, math-fonts

I know there are different mathematical fonts, as listed in this answer [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode) . However, this is not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to actually change the core design of how latex writes symbols and equations (i.e how the \sum sign is drawn and such)? I'm asking this because I am trying to write a paper replicating the font-style of the physics and maths book from the 80s. I will show you an example.
 This is LaTeX's normal math font
[image]

and this is the kind of change I am looking for

[image: Image taking from Wald, General Relativity (1984)]

Of course, I am not looking for this exact specific design, this was just supposed to be an example. Is what I'm asking possible?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can take a look at the [maths fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) page  of the *LaTeX Font Catalogue*.

Comment: Oh wow, I knew that Catalogue but for some reason I have never noticed the maths fonts section! That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: There's also this thread, for Open Type fonts with math support: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098/134574