# How to use mathcal fonts with charter font from mathdesign?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Here's an example that uses the [mathdesign](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign?lang=en) package to implement the Charter fonts:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
   $H \quad \mathcal H \quad \mathscr H$
\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image]

According to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124/10628), I expected `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` to yield different results. How do I get fonts similar to these

[image]

while also using the Charter fonts. (This last image is borrowed from the answer cited above.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer you cite is not specific to `mathdesign` and essentially shows the default for `\mathcal`. Font packages may change it.

With `mathdesign`, `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` are synonyms, unless the (undocumented) option `cal=cmcal` is passed to the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

$H \quad \mathcal{H} \quad \mathscr{H}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid `\mathcal H` and prefer `\mathcal{H}`. Trust me.

---

How to find the undocumented option?

The Charter font is managed with the subpackage `mdbch.sty`, which has

```
\if@MD@cmcal
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdcal}{OMS}{xmdcmsy}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{mdcal}{bold}{OMS}{xmdcmsy}{b}{n}%
\else
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdcal}{OMS}{mdbch}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{mdcal}{bold}{OMS}{mdbch}{b}{n}%
\fi
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{mdcal}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdscr}{OMS}{mdbch}{m}{n}%

\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{mdscr}%
\SetSymbolFont{mdscr}{bold}{OMS}{mdbch}{b}{n}%
```

Not how I'd write it, but that's a different matter. It seems reasonable that `xmdcmsy` refers to the Computer Modern `\mathcal`. Indeed, `mdfont.def` has

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Computer Modern Symbol
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

  \def\MD@font@name{xmdcmsy}
  \DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{\MD@font@name}{\skewchar\font48 }
  \DeclareFontShape{OMS}{\MD@font@name}{m}{n}{%
    <5><6><7><8><9><10>sgen*[\cmsy@ratio]cmsy%
    <10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88> s*[\cmsy@ratio] cmsy10%
  }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{OMS}{\MD@font@name}{b}{n}{%
    <5><6><7><8><9>sgen*[\cmsy@ratio]cmbsy%
    <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88> s*[\cmsy@ratio] cmbsy10%
  }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{OMS}{\MD@font@name}{mb}{n}{%
    <5><6><7><8><9>sgen*[\cmsy@ratio]cmbsy%
    <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88> s*[\cmsy@ratio] cmbsy10%
  }{}
```

which essentially means the `cmsy` font is subject to a suitable scaling for making it compatible with the main font.

OK, not it's a matter to look how to make `\if@MD@cmcal` return true. If we look for it in `mathdesign.sty`, we find

```
%% Type of calligraphic alphabet
\newif\if@MD@cmcal  \@MD@cmcalfalse

\define@key{MD}{cal}[cmcal]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{cmcal}}{\@MD@cmcaltrue }
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{script}}{\@MD@cmcalfalse}{}}}
```

This means that if the option `cal=cmcal` is passed, the conditional will return true. With nothing or `cal=absolutelywhatever` the conditional will return false with `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` becoming synonyms.

Actually also typing just `cal` would do, so you can save some keystrokes and say

```
\usepackage[charter,cal]{mathdesign}
```

Why isn't this option mentioned in the manual? Who knows?