# How to write numbers with a vertical line crossed on the corner?

Tags: symbols

[image]

How to write this 2? I tried to google it but I cannot find any solution...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode

Comment: Take this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZdhj.png from answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode

Comment: Nice resource from MarianG. and Douglas Mencken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments and suggestions below your question, one can use the `bbold` package to achieve the desired output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb 2^{\mathcal U}$
\end{document}
```

Running it with `pdflatex` produces

[image]

Comment: THX! That works!