# mathbfcal for LaTeX

Tags: math-fonts

I typically typeset my documents in `xelatex`. With `unicode-math` and Cambria Math fonts a variety of math-styles are possible. This time the requirement is to use just `pdflatex`. How can I type (with STIX fonts preferably) in the `\mathbfcal` style? I am aware of this [popular post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/71825), however, I cannot find any prescription there.

I am adding a minimal example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mleftright,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbfscr{G}$
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image],

which is the bold script style, not the bold calligraphic, which I am used to

[image]
For completeness, this is the solution using `bm` package

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mleftright,mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\bm{\mathcal{G}}$
$\mathcal{G}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with (`\usepackage{bm}` and then) `\bm{\mathcal{N}}`.

Comment: @Werner it gives me a message `Too many symbol fonts declared`. I have in the preamble: `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mleftright,mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stix}`

Comment: Try with a different load order: `\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mleftright,mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}`

Comment: since you have stix you have the bold symbols already and don't need bm `\mathbfscr`

Comment: @yarchik as you see from the  comments it _always_ helps if you show in the question a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: @Werner It seems the `bm` solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the stix bold calligraphic

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright,mathtools}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{LS2}{stixcal}{b}{n}
\begin{document}
    $\mathscr{G}$ $\mathcal{G}$ 
    $\mathbfscr{G}$ $\mathbfcal{G}$ 
\end{document}
```

You could use the cm one if you wish

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright,mathtools}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\begin{document}
    $\mathscr{G}$ $\mathcal{G}$ 
    $\mathbfscr{G}$ $\mathbfcal{G}$ 
\end{document}
```

Although you might want to redefine the non bold one to use cm as well (or you may not)

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright,mathtools}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\begin{document}
    $\mathscr{G}$ $\mathcal{G}$ 
    $\mathbfscr{G}$ $\mathbfcal{G}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for completeness, can you please comment why in  `cm`  the bold calligraphic fonts are accessible with `\mathbfcal` whereas this is not the case for `stix`.

Comment: @yarchik after the last edit I show that command accessing stix (in the first case) or cm (in the second and third cases)

Comment: Thank you, this is a comprehensive answer.