# What do the unicode-math range labels mean

Tags: unicode-math

The documentation for unicode-math says this about the various labels for range:

> In unicode-math, these ranges are indicated with the following (hopefully self-explanatory) labels:
>
> up, it, bb, bbit, scr, cal, bfcal, frak, tt, sfup, sfit, bfup, bfit, bfscr, bffrak, bfsfup, bfsfit

These **are not** self-explanatory to me. What are each of their meanings?

Answer (score 5):

They correspond to [the `\sym...` math alphabets.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode/437882#437882)  So,

```
\setmathfont[range=up]{Neo Euler}
```

changes the `\symup` alphabet to Neo Euler, `range=it` changes `\symit`, and so on.

Another thing that isn’t intuitive is that this does **not** change `\mathrm`, `\mathbf` or `\mathit`,  These default to your main font family.  You can change them with a different command, `\setmathrm`.  You can also pass `unicode-math` an option to make them aliases for `\symup`, `\symbfup` and `\symit`.

By default, the `\sym...` alphabets are for standalone math symbols, such as `\symbfup{j}`, and the `\math...` alphabets are for words in math mode, such as `\mathrm{iff}`.  You will notice a major difference between the kerning of `\mathrm{iff}` and `\symup{iff}`!

Another thing that’s not intuitive is that `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` are, by default, set to the same alphabet, but you can override either one to make it different.

One last thing that’s not intuitive is that, as of 2021, the `range=` and `version=` options of `\setmathfont` are incompatible, so you can either use `range=` or have different math versions, but not both.

So, one of my go-to examples is the Euler identity with constants set in Neo Euler and everything else in (a clone of) Palatino:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}, 
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler identities]

In the above example, `\symup{i}`, `\symup{e}` and `\symup{\pi}` (or `\uppi`) are all changed to Neo Euler, but the the operators `sin` and `cos` remain in `\mathrm`, and `x` and the digits are from the main math font.

Answer (score 3):

they are upright italic, blackboard bold, script calligraphic, bold calligraphic etc which correspond to the Unicode math alphabets as listed for example at

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/#alphabets

Answer (score 3):

You can add prepend `\sym` to these labels to get the `unicode-math` math font switching command corresponding to it. (E.g. `it` sets the font for characters which can be inserted with `\symit`)

Then section 5.4 "All (the rest) of the mathematical styles" of the documentation contains a table (at time of writing this is table 7) listing for each of these switches which style/shape/series it corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

Visually, with images from the free app BabelMap:

[image: mas1]

[image: mas2]

[image: mas3]

[image: mas4]

[image: mas5]

[image: mas6]

[image: mas7]

[image: mas8]

The purpose of the alphabets in a mathfont is that there is semantic meaning in serif/sans-serif, bold/italic/upright, plain/calligraphic/fraktur/blackboard, Latin/Greek, uppercase/lowercase, proportional-width/monospaced, so the font has to have all of the glyphs, no matter what the font's textmode alphabet is.

Some combinations aren't used or don't exist, though: e.g., there is no Greek Fraktur.

Comment: The unicode-math doc talked about semantic meaning but is there a comprehensive list of the semantic meaning somewhere?

Comment: @greendiod Ask a separate question so the mathematicians on site here have a better chance of seeing it. I think the answer is likely to be "no" to the "comprehensive" part of the question, since the set of symbols is open-ended: "no  collection  of  mathematical symbols can ever be considered complete; mathematicians and other scientists are continually inventing new mathematical symbols" (https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr25/). Best result I suppose would be a "most up-to-date current" list of symbols.

Comment: @greendiod Maybe there are א ("for the first transfinite cardinal") symbols :) Then there is the list of non-latin/Greek symbols, like those in Arabic script... This symbol  could come in handy one day for counting infinite multitudes of a quantity.

Comment: The set of symbols is open-ended but the set of symbol meaning classes may be finite ??? ;)