# Write strange i in Latex

Tags: fonts, characters

I saw this letter i in some papers and wanted to use it in one of my documents; couldn't find how to get it to appear.[image]

Comment: `$i_\mathbb{R}$` with `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/5764)

Comment: No, already tried that one, @CarLaTeX. Didn't find the fontstyle there either, Werner.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a minimal example. As your question is, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @PedroGarcía: Is that because there's no `\mathbb{R}` listed in the answer? That answer just shows the first couple of letters of the alphabet, but surely you should have noted that, right?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be Iwona Condensed:

[image]

or just Iwona:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona} % remove condensed for standard width
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

La aplicaci\'on $i_{\mathbb{R}}$

\end{document}
```

In general, one can consult the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) for to search for a particular font.