# How to type this font style in latex?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, pdftex, math-fonts

I refer to this site: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf and find a lot of font types I want. But this material just doesn't show a clear example of how to type the font style it has listed.

The following font styles are the ones I need. But I can't type it according to the PDF. Could anyone show a clear example of how to type them and other styles in the material?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)

Comment: @Sandy G Thanks for your reply. I find the font style in the link. But the **Edit3** of the accepted answer doesn't present a clear example how to type them. Therefore, I am a little confused about how to use.

Comment: Initially I thought this was a duplicate, but as OP indicates, the issue isn't about finding the style, but rather producing the output. The `mma` font is old and may no longer be supported. The linked question and answers do not actually address this. So I vote to reopen.

Comment: There is an archival package for the Mathematica 3.0 fonts at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/Mathematica3.0 but since it's compressed, and I didn't unpack it, it's unclear whether the fonts are actually included; I suspect not, as the description says "Virtual TeX fonts that can be used with the PostScript fonts distributed with Mathematica 3.0."  So unless you already have the fonts, this won't be much help.