# How to type 'U' like this?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I surf the net, but I can't find a clear example on how to type **U** like this. Could anyone show a related code example?
[image]

Comment: I'd say that's `\mathcal{U}` with Palatino fonts (e.g. package `newpxmath`).

Comment: @campa Yeah! Thanks for your answer. It is the `newpxmath` package that works for me. There are so many packages in Latex, I am new to it so I don't load this but the default one before. Moreover, I still don't know how to type the font in the [question I asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627206/how-to-type-this-font-style-in-latex), where I find the style I want. Still thanks for your reply again. It is helpful not just the abundant text left!!!!

Comment: In principle it's as simple as `\usepackage[cal=mma]{mathalfa}` and then `\mathcal{...}` but that's a commercial font, so it won't work unless you have it...

Comment: @campa So does this mean the `newpxmath` package contain the commercial font?

Comment: No, `newpx` is a free font. But the `mma` in your other question is commercial (I think; anyway it's not part of TeX Live).