# need help for finding a family font

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Although I have searched to find the family font used in the following formula
[image]
I was not able to find it. I'm gonna typeset the red letters as they are in the formula, however, I don't know how to do it. Meanwhile, I used the tips suggested in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture) but it did not work out for me. It would be kind of you if you help me.

Comment: See [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/5764)

Comment: There remains the option of including the character as an image, but it looks like that your image is a somewhat-low-quality raster image and not e.g. vector graphics taken from a PDF. Still, you can retrace the boundary with some font creation program. ■ Even Detexify doesn't help here.

Comment: Where are you taken your image, please? Have you the pdf file?

Comment: Dear @Sebastiano I don't have its pdf file. it was taken from a book named "The nuclear many-body problem"

Comment: You might want to check the specimens in the [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) and [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) manuals for a decent match.  Alternatively, you can use any OpenType or TrueType script font with `\setmathfont[range=scr]` in `unicode-math`.

Comment: And Who Is the author?

Comment: Dear @Sebastiano the author is Peter Ring

Comment: Hi . I have seen the book. It Is old and It Is of springer. What Is the Page please?

Comment: Dear @Sebastiano, the page is 265

Comment: @Davislor Hi very kind: here there is the book. http://hadron.physics.fsu.edu/~akbar/NuclearTextBook.pdf. I think that is the old euler script mathscr in math mode. It is since 1980 and I think that is a pure TeX.

Answer (score 2):

It is probable that your text is from the pre-computer typesetting time. The closest font seems to be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{HR}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am agree totally with you.

Answer (score 1):

The notation does not appear to be standard. The screenshot below is taken from a recent Springer volume:

Younes W., Gogny D.M., Berger JF. (2019) Hartree-Fock-Bogoliubov Theory. In: A Microscopic Theory of Fission Dynamics Based on the Generator Coordinate Method. Lecture Notes in Physics, vol 950. Springer, Cham. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-04424-4_1

and uses only standard fonts.

[image]