# How to use the (restrained) "CM calligraphic, cmsy" font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

How to use the (restrained) "CM calligraphic, cmsy", mentioned in "[What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)"?
Can you provide a minimum working example please?
[image]

Comment: why the -1 vote?

Comment: Let me preface this by saying that I do not give negative votes; perhaps you could do it yourself. If I understand you correctly, you want normal and bold calligraphic characters?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Sebastiano. Of course I can do it by myself, but I do not understand where "cm" or "cmsy" is contained....in which package?

Comment: I think here: \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a solution that employs the [mathalpha](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package. Aside: the screenshot shown in the OP's query originates from the user guide of the `mathalpha` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABC\dots XYZ}$ \quad $\mathbfcal{ABC\dots XYZ}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer @Mico!!!!! Many many thanks!!!! :-)

Comment: @limone - You're most welcome.

Comment: @limone Please, can you give the green check mark to Mico seen that is the great answer? Thank you.

Comment: Done :-) Btw, I would have accepted both Answers, many thanks to both! :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks for being so generous! (Incidentally, I upvoted your answer before posting mine...)

Comment: @Mico Don't be worry. I am happy, in this mode.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\begin{document}
  $\mathcal{ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRRSTUVZ}$, $\mathbfcal{ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRRSTUVZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I did not know about the ```\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}``` command, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have noticed that, for the **not**-bold case, I get what you get only if I add this line
```\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}   {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}```, just after 
```\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}```

Comment: @limone for the non bold, you can simply use `\mathcal` no definition is needed, it is standard latex

Comment: Thanks a lot @David Carlisle.... Initially, I indeed just used ```\mathcal```, but with just that command, I did not get my desired font... but then, just by adding ```\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}   {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}```, I was able to get the desired output.... I do not why to be honest...... :-)

Comment: @limone that's the default definition so you are just using standard `\mathcal`

Comment: ah ok, thanks :-)