# Can you identify this script font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

When reading a book, I saw a script "I" (capital i) of a font that I haven't been able to identify. It looks like this:

[image: Script I]

Does anyone have an idea what font this is? I would like to use this letter when writing relational algebra.

I've searched for it, including by going through this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode), but haven't had any luck.

In case someone is wondering, I found it p. 260 of the book *Fundamentals of Database Systems* (7th ed.) by Elmasri and Navathe.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `\frak{}`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I thought about `\frak`, it looks a bit similar, but that's not the one

Comment: Do you have a digital copy, i.e. a pdf? The fonts can be looked up in there.

Comment: www.whatfontis.com suggests  https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Bertholdr-Mainzer-Fraktur.font?text=I

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel after reading your comment I looked up the fonts that I could find throught the properties of my PDF viewer. I think I googled all of them but could not find any match. Is it possible that it does appear on that list?

Comment: @Rmano That's the closest I've seen so far! It's gonna be quite the adventure if I intend to get this one working with latex

Comment: It's possible. If, for example, the character is included as an image, it would not be part of any font, so wouldn't show up in the list. But all the fonts used in the PDF should show up in the list, provided your viewer is doing its job.

Comment: Perhaps the authors state the tools/fonts used somewhere in the preamble of the text.