# Different font packages besides mathbb

Tags: fonts, packages

I am new to LaTeX. I only know of the mathbb package since that one is ubiquitous. I am trying to replicate this typeface here. Can someone please tell me what package to use for this? And from where I can learn about the packages other than mathbb and what style of font they result in?

[image]

Comment: there is no  package called mathbb, I think you mean the amsfonts package. try `texdoc symbols` which will show a large collection of symbols and fonts set up for latex

Comment: That is `\mathcal{R}`, you don't need a package to use this command.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot.

Comment: Or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode is a bit more direct answer to your question.